# Too many up votes for duplicate questions from new users

Tags: feature-request, upvotes, privileges

Duplicate questions are a perennial problem, and for all the time I've been reviewing close votes I've come across many low value duplicates. That is, duplicates that add no value, because they do not reinstate the same problem in different terms. Duplicates that would never have been posted if the poster had bothered to do even cursory searching on SO first.

But now it seems I'm seeing many more of these low value duplicates getting up votes. I've seen cases where the low value duplicates get *more* upvotes than the, better quality,  original question.

My guess is that I am seeing the effect of numerous newer members, who do not know or care about duplicates. They upvote the new questions faster than the more experienced members can close them.

I suggest that we need to raise the bar to reduce this effect. That is, we ought to increase the reputation required to have the privilege to vote on questions.

Comment: You're assuming that the low rep users do those upvotes. I'm not sure that's true.

Comment: ^^ That. I've even seen cases where I *swear* (due to the timing) a high-enough-rep-to-know-better user posting the answer to the obvious dup also upvoted it (rather than downvoting/closing) in what I can only assume is an attempt to get people to look at it and upvote their answer.

Comment: It happens like that because of the more deeper problem - the "QUESTION ACTUALITY TIME-FRAME PROBLEM" (old questions just collect rep - they don't gather new attention, which is gathered by new ones (also much better DOWNVOTES and attention closures). I did upvote your Q, but know that -2 ppl cast of not so deep thought about this fundamental problem.

Comment: What I find extremely frustrating is that people so zealously try to close duplicate questions that they fail to recognize questions that are similar but subtly different from the original. I try to always up-vote these to counter honestly. I can't tell you how many times I've googled a question, found someone with the exact same issue only to see that it is closed as a duplicate of a question that doesn't apply to the situation. Probably my biggest pet peeve with stackoverflow lately.

Comment: @KellyGendron: In such cases a comment explaining the difference should be your weapon of choice.  The new question almost certainly *isn't* worthy of an upvote.  Part of "shows research effort" is linking similar-but-not-relevant questions that you read and explaining the difference.  Also account for signposts pointing to questions that are somewhat different, with an accepted answer that thoroughly covers both variants.

Answer (score 7):

That's a bit of a convoluted solution to the problem, don't you think?

It also ignores a bit of an inconvenient truth: sometimes, folks can't find the original *because no one bothered to vote for it*. I run into this a fair bit; I'll remember a great answer on a topic and search for it, only to find half a dozen more highly-voted questions instead, all either irrelevant or just lacking the answer I'm looking for.

...Then I remember that *I* didn't vote for the good question either. And get sad.

So, y'know, remember to vote.

Comment: SO needs to rework how it handles duplicates. There needs to be a promotion mechanism so the best question/answer eventually becomes the first found.

Comment: I think I missed the step from "I'll remember a great answer on a topic" to "I didn't vote for the good question either".  Great answers do not imply good questions.  If a great, highly upvoted answer is not discoverable because the question accrued few votes, maybe the search algorithm needs to be tweaked to include the answer votes too.

Comment: Maybe. Still, if I find a question that exactly matches a problem I'm facing, I should be voting for it.