# Restrict up vote rights

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, privileges

I'm feeling like I'm going to draw lots of fire with this question, but this is bugging me for long time now, so I feel like I need get it out.

So the main question/request here: **I think we should change the minimum requirements in order to cast an upvote**.

**Why**? Because I truly believe that SO is aiming to be a database for the best possible programming solutions and the *only* metric for a quality of an answer is upvotes/downvotes ratio. 
But do those upvotes/downvotes have any meaning if they are being cast by just some random people? It seems that all the SE sites think not, otherwise any user could upvote/downvote.

**So to the point** — I'm seeing way too many very low quality answers with way too many upvotes (I won't post examples because I don't want to create any Meta effects — if people feeling the same — they will understand what I'm talking about) and thus creating a very low/misleading content on the first page of practically any Google search result.

**The reason** for that (I believe) is because the minimum requirement for an upvote is only 15(!) rep, which you can easily achieve with some random edits that in no way indicate the level of your skill.

**So what I propose** 
I think that a minimum upvote/downvote rep should behave the same as tag scores, e.g., not by some general rep (from edits/questions/bounties/accepted answers), but **by the amount of upvotes you have earned by answering questions** — that means that, for example, in order to upvote/downvote you should get at least 15 upvotes on answers.

I don't think this is a very high requirement, but I think it is necessary in order to improve the quality of this site.

What do you think?

---

**Edit**: 
This question wasn't intended to hurt anyone in particular and thus I haven't added links with examples, so I'd appreciate that people will refrain from massive down voting my main account

Thank you

Comment: While I sympathize on the thoughts behind this suggested change, I would like to draw your attention to a possible degradation of SO users' motivation to answer "noobie" questions since the OP will not be able to upvote a good answer. This applies to rather uncommon topics even more so.

Comment: Related: [Bad questions gaining fast (<5 min) upvotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288092/2564301). Especially when it's a homework question (not the [good kind](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288270/2564301)), where I suspect the upvotes come from class mates who'd also really *really* want that Easiest Solution.

Comment: Should we restrict downvotes to only to people who have been downvoted X times, also? I think the barrier for entry to upvotes is set low for a reason, and increasing that to effectively 10 times what it is now is a big jump.

Comment: @connexo OP wouldn't be able to upvote but could still accept the answer, which is motivation enough to answer a question, no ?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to bump voting privileges from 15 and 125 (up/down) to 150 rep, correct? If so, that changes the [number of users that can up vote from over 1M to less than 300K](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/339016/reputation-levels)

Comment: @TZHX: No, that seems daft - being downvoted is a sign of *lack* of quality, whereas being upvoted is (or should be) a sign of *positive* quality. Restricting downvotes to those who have been upvoted X times would make more sense.

Comment: @JonS It was daft on purpose.

Comment: Meh - I hardly ever upvote anything these days:(

Comment: @MartinJames that's my point exactly. it seems like only low rep users upvote, while all the high rep users just gave up on the whole system.

Comment: @connexo I do think it will have a positive effect, "noobie" question being usually duplicates, this could limit rep whoring on their question. and if the question is interesting enough, someone will answer, and if the answer is good enough, peers with vote right will upvote it. So it could end up with an amelioration of overall quality instead of a degradation (unless you see SO as a help center and not a quality aimed Q/A base)

Comment: @TZHX: So what was the point of it? Basically it looked like you were trying to claim that a reasonable suggestion was equivalent to a blatantly unreasonable one...

Comment: @Tensibai I'm inclined to think the suggested mechanism would indeed *increase* the quality of answers. No incentives to "spam" low quality answers to low quality questions (because users would know they won't get upvotes by high rep users if they don't post quality answers).

Comment: @JonS The first sentence of the comment was a joke. I'm sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: @David: I find it harder to find something to upvote than I (think) used to, but I don't believe it's because I "gave up". It's just that the more you learn, the more you are aware of the merits and demerits of questions and answers. I still *down* vote with gusto.

Comment: Answer questions to help others. Sometimes you won't get the upvotes you deserve, sometimes you'll get more.. keep on answering for the "higher purpose" of helping and it will end up improving the community. The current mechanism is, in my opinion, flawed because it's fueling the "get more upvote then you deserve" for low quality answers, so it discourages high rep users for answering has they sometimes get less upvotes than low quality answers simply because "noobie" can't appreciate the quality of their contributions.

Comment: there is somewhat related, [interesting idea to get rid of _first day voting_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183109/the-association-bonus-should-not-enable-users-to-vote-on-every-site/183568#comment781260_237661), "...wanna vote? stick with us! (for at least a day or two)"

Comment: I've seen, on more than one occasion, the entire front page +1'd all the way, just because some idiot wanted a badge and decided to shotgun upvote everything.  I've seen, far too many times, extremely low-quality questions upvoted for no obvious reason.  In both scenarios, I'd venture a guess that it's new, low-rep users doing this.  I've got no proof, but I'd *hope* (as misguided as that probably is) that seasoned users wouldn't be doing this.  You've got my upvote.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I remember I did that, just in the other direction (didn't get my badge through)

Comment: Oeh, this is a good alternative to my suggestion of "[Penalty for answering help-vampire questions? Or reward closure?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299353/penalty-for-answering-help-vampire-questions-or-reward-closure)"

Comment: I don't have an answer but I will suggest that there is commercial value in having earned reputation. Especially as people point to Github, SO and other locations as part of a portfolio these days. Consider the outcome likely to be something similar to the link antics of folks waging SEO battles at some point.

Comment: Answers on questions that are very very easy to answer and are obviously noob questions get the most upvotes, that's a sad fact...

Comment: We need a 'Buffy badge' for some measure of downvoting answers to questions that are shown to be dups.  If you get the 'Buffy', you get the -2's for the last x downvotes reversed.

Comment: Related to [Too many up votes for duplicate questions from new users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252069/too-many-up-votes-for-duplicate-questions-from-new-users).

Comment: _I've got no proof, but I'd hope (as misguided as that probably is) that seasoned users wouldn't be doing this._ I remember someone saying in Meta that they up vote all answers that aren't spam or otherwise not an answer because "they tried". I can't recall their rep level though.

Comment: But why is everyone so fussed about downvoting and upvoting and reputation if it is genuine about learning? this makes me wonder. Well i recall i once clicked on a post which was posted in 1min and it was long and i saw someone already downvote and i wondered when did he/she even read the question. Either i love the site because i can get my answer on what i want.

Comment: It took me a year and a half to be able to _comment_ on posts, so in that time, I'd post an answer that should have been a comment, only to have it flagged as 'should have been a comment.' It's incredibly prohibitive to get enough rep to be an active member of any community, and this would likely serve to make it even more prohibitive.

Comment: @KymikoLoco there is a reason why it is prohibitive. If a certain site wants to be on top, he needs to keep his content high quality. There is a good reason why Google hires only the best programmers in the world.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't believe that's an apt comparison for not letting newbies access to the site as a whole sooner. There isn't an interview process, I don't submit my resume to SO, (although some Wikis have that requirement!) so there is no way to know who you are potentially turning away.

Comment: @KymikoLoco I didn't set the rules, but I believe in most of them. This is your choice as an end user to "take it or leave it". This is being said, I don't want you to be offended, and I'm sure you are a prompt programmer, it's just every system has it cons and pros, but this specific one usually works well.

Comment: I agree with the title, but not the suggestion to accomplish it. i'm on the boat of too many low quality question are being upvoted too, but, i think my definition of "low quality" differs from yours. There is nothing "low quality" about a question that can be answered quickly or easily. Those are often the most useful questions on the site, hence the immense number of upvotes they receive. we don't need a grace period restriction (the rep requirement already does that,) so i'm not sure what i'd suggest to fix it short of slightly increasing the requirement.

Comment: I think this issue is a symptom of beginner/low-quality questions, advanced/high-quality questions, new users, and long-time users all getting tossed into the same bucket.

Comment: @KevinB this is exactly why I didn't address questions in this thread. I don't feel like it is hard to handle bad questions (high rep users can easily close them), I find it way harder to deal with very bad answers with many upvotes.

Comment: I think there's another discussion about that already, with a fix in the works.

Comment: What exactly are you focusing on? Answers that are bad in that the offer poor advice, answers that are bad in that they don't provide any explanation, or answers that are bad because the question was too easy (or, not bad, but not deserving of a lot of votes).

Comment: see, that's a different problem entirely. If the answer is truly bad advice at the time it is posted, it's highly likely that someone who knows better will vote or comment to correct it. If it still receives a lot of upvotes in a short period of time, maybe it isn't as bad of an answer as you think and a comment will suffice. If instead you're talking about very old posts, that's yet another problem, where it may have been a good idea back then, but isn't anymore by today's standards.

Comment: @pnuts, I posted a [request for data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299930/voting-history-statistics-request) from the community managers. Hopefully we can get some hard data that will help in this (and other) discussions.

Comment: @connexo OP is only one person and can only upvote once, so that's not a particularly large effect.

Comment: How about a weighted vote?  Your opinion is worth more if you're respected in the field, right? So make it proportional to your rep? You could also narrow this down by tags.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart that's more or less what the most downvoted answer on this thread proposed, no? I would agree with you, but such offers will be mob-downvoted, simply because on over high rep user there are 100K low rep ones who think otherwise. Regarding the tag, I thought about it, but this will probably very limit the voting system.

Comment: _let me upvote this question_

Comment: This assumes that only very low rep users vote or use the site in the wrong way. I have seen people of many levels of reputation using it wrong. I.E. users with more than 1k rep answering blatantly duplicate questions. 1k may not be so much, but is more than what you are suggesting. People vote mostly vote because something has helped them not because the quality of the text. The problem with this idea is, where do we draw the line? What is enough rep? Having high rep doesn't mean you know of quality. Nothing is perfect, I don't see a valid reason a to stop up-voting good content.

Comment: Makes me think that I have downvoted like only once in 4 years. I remember too badly how discouraging it is being a newbie and being downvoted without remorse. But now  I come to  think that  if experienced users downvote more of those low quality upvoted questions (and answers) then it will provide balance. I notice sometimes that the OP's criteria to accepting answer is speed and "that it works" and the answer in question can be badly formatted, with flaws in design, unexplained blob of code.

Comment: @connexo - I disagree. I think when you balance everything out; it becomes apparent that the potential gains from this increased rep-threshold outweighs that risk. Further, it's not just the OP who can upvote. Stack is viewed by oodles of people. If a question gets attention, it will generate the deserved rep.

Comment: Regarding meta effect, Shog9 posted a [workaround](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261353/229356) using systempuntoout's StackPrinter service.

Answer (score 148):

I have to disagree. My impression of the voting system is that it is designed to increase engagement with the site, even by very casual users. It's part of what distinguishes Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange as a whole) from a web forum.

Somewhat autobiographically, I think of it is this way: I'm mainly active on three Stack Exchange sites (Stack Overflow, AcademiaSE, and OpenData). But, I also sometimes visit *[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)*, and *[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)* when I have questions about something. The fact that I can up-vote on those sites even though I hardly ever ask or answer anything on them makes my experience of those other sites more enjoyable and engaging. For the user of another Stack Exchange site that happens across an Stack Overflow Q&A or just a very casual user who has an Stack Exchange account, but doesn't participate much on any site, their ability to express opinions on questions and answers is an integral part of the larger gamification scheme that is Stack Exchange.

Simply because someone has low rep doesn't mean they aren't knowledgeable or, more importantly, that they aren't able to correctly express when an answer was or was not helpful to them.

I agree that there might be useful tweaks to the voting system (e.g., earning variable numbers of points from users with different reputations; modifying the incentive structure to encourage voting by high-rep users [beyond the [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) and [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) badges]). But, I also think keeping the voting threshold low is important for the broader experience of the site.

Comment: I can agree to some extent but saying "*Simply because someone has low rep doesn't mean they aren't knowledgeable or, more importantly, that they aren't able to correctly express when an answer was or was not helpful to them.*" is like saying "*simply because someone doesn't have a MD doesn't mean he can't be a Doctor*". That statement could be potentially true, but will you agree to be operated by a school boy? I don't think so. We usually don't take such chances in real life in any aspect, rather we expect that if someone has some skill he needs to prove it first in order for us to trust him

Comment: @DavidArenburg Fair enough, but it's just as easy to have a counter-example. If [Tim Berners-Lee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1162584/timbl?tab=profile) wants to swing by StackOverflow occasionally and cast some votes but only ever asks [that one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345230/how-can-i-see-the-internal-compile-commands-which-fail-in-a-go-get-installatio?stw=2), I'd be perfectly fine with that.

Comment: If Tim would want to truly participate in SO voting system, he could easily answer some simple question or two, get some upvotes and here you go. The privilege to express your opinion on such a site content (IMO), should be restricted by some minimal effort on a user's side. Otherwise, how would you even know that it is truly him?

Comment: Well, so to keep some part-time passer by happy, we should support the upvotes from full-time present learners upvoting anything "cool" ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg "will you agree to be operated by a school boy" ? No, but I might agree to be operated by a doctor that his older brother (with at least 15 rep) _recommended_.  That's a better analogy for voting.

Comment: But you automatically earn **100** for joining other sites. This is significantly higher than the 15 needed to upvote.

Comment: @MichaelChirico it's not about rep rather upvotes on provided answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Having an operation performed on you is hardly as serious as who you allow to subjectively judge the value of posts on a QA site.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I just made an extreme example in order to illustrate my point, that's all.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes but I'm highlighting just how different they are because I don't think the voting is as big an issue as you do at all. Is the signal noise actively interrupting you finding answers or does it bother you because the system doesn't work as well as it could/should?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan let me put it that way- I'm seeing way too many pure c*** answers on this site with way too many upvotes simply because the answer sounds confident/his output accidentally matches the desired output/he is popular/ he is using a popular tool made by some other popular guy. I feel this is very destructive to this site. I also believe that a plain wrong code can be sometime destructive to certain end users.

Comment: @David, if the answers given is crappy, then shouldn't the comment section be used to generate more discussions on why it's a bad answer? this would generate more positive feedback and engagement. Everyone should have a voice. - the newbies can learn from the noob questions, while the experienced one can tackle the challenging questions.

Comment: @AngelKoh i'm using the comment section a lot, but you can't retract 6 upvotes that happened within the first 5 minutes even if the OP ignores you. Many times the comment stops the mad upvote stream, but usually people don't want to downvote because it will cost them their rep. Neither they will edit the answer in order to retract their vote because they afraid of revenge. There are also many old answers that no one even look at your comment, but that another issue I guess.

Comment: @David, it's anecdotal, but i do look at all comments when i'm searching for an answer on SO (I don't want to implement a wrong solution that'll come back to bite me later). If the answer solve my problem, I'd give them an upvote.

Comment: Another possibility is a more gradual increase in upvoting rights: 1 upvote per day with 15 rep, 5 per day by 100 rep, 10 by 250, from 500 as it is now (or something like that). New users get voting rights quite early and get rewarded with additional voting rights when they gain rep, thus also addressing the engagement point @Thomas mentioned.

Comment: 'because someone has low rep doesn't mean they aren't knowledgeable' - good point for some high-rep users who suddenly start to see lot of low quality content. However, it's just their standards have raised, not content quality lowered.

Comment: _"Designed to increase engagement"_ in a _"facebook-style-no-negative-feedback"_
 way, yeah... just incessant, mindless, like, like, like, like, like... because I only have a like button.

Comment: In line with pnuts suggestion, identify super-voters as those that have provided answers with a high number of up-votes. Allow those super-voters to up or down vote with more authority.

Comment: I have to agree with @Thomas. Some of us are just new to the party, and that doesn't reflect our knowledge or ability to determine the usefulness of an answer, or the appropriateness of a question. I only got involved a few weeks ago because I had some challenges in Python, and every time I Googled, I invariably found the answer on SO. So I got involved. I have decades of experience with computers, programming, and Excel, and have tried to provide helpful answers where I can. It is just that for the past few years that wasn't my main focus, so I missed the groundswell of SO's beginnings.

Comment: "Simply because someone has low rep doesn't mean they aren't knowledgeable or, more importantly, that they aren't able to correctly express when an answer was or was not helpful to them." Agreed. It does mean,  however, that I am less enclined to trust her judgement. She still needs to prove her value to me. Wait, that's my definition of "reputation".

Answer (score 99):

> I don't think this is a very high requirement

I emphatically disagree.  15 upvotes are the equivalent of 150 reputation.  That's non-trivial for new users.  More importantly, you are making it harder for users to even get those first 15 upvotes in the first place.  If it takes 15 upvotes for one user to vote, each of those 15 upvoters also need 15 upvotes and....   Basically new users would not be able to vote for a *very* long time. And once they did, I think they'd be *more tempted to vote incorrectly*.  They might drop "pity" vote more often to help other new users.  Which is exactly what you're trying to avoid: voting for non-quality reasons.

As for restricting the upvote privilege

> by the amount of upvotes you have earned by answering questions

Even if your proposed limit were something like 2 upvotes on answers (the equivalent of 20 rep), the restriction of getting the reputation from posts is unnecessary.  **You don't need to be able to create posts of your own in order to judge the usefulness and clarity of other posts.** Upvotes don't exist solely for "technical accuracy" (although that's a very important consideration).  Other things like formatting, ease of understanding the explanation, and grammar are important factors of post quality.  And most users can accurately judge posts on these merits.  After all, the most amazingly comprehensive answer to a problem is not useful if no one can understand it.

I don't like the idea of further crippling new users to that extent.  Raising the voting requirements would certainly create more lurkers and fewer answerers. I mean what's the point of having an account if you can't even do anything with it?   Most of my questions have already been asked, and I can't even upvote the helpful answers?  And no one else can upvote my stuff because they also don't have the privilege.  **People vote because it's an important part of contributing to the community**.  Making it that much harder to vote would turn off a lot of new users.

I also believe some of the problems you point out aren't symptoms of the low rep requirement to upvote.  Instead, they are problems that are inherent in people not understanding the culture of SO (and not bothering to learn).  How many NAAs have you seen where users say "I can't comment yet, so please don't downvote [insert comment]"?  Raising the upvote requirement might lead to even more VLQ posts that fit the "Please don't add Thanks as an answer" pattern.

And as for

> But are those upvotes/downvotes have any meaning if they are being cast by just some random people? It seems that all the SE sites think not, otherwise any user could upvote/downvote.

This is fallacious.  Of course voting should be user-independent as long as the *voting itself is not random*.  How many users do you think vote randomly (and not actually because their standards for "helpful" and "clear" are different)?  The minimum requirements are efforts to prevent spammers and voting fraud.

---

**TL;DR**

I think this would create more problems than it would solve because it is too strict of a requirement.

Comment: Being able to convey programming ideas as well written answers is _hard_. I think a lot of more experienced uses forget that.

Comment: It is very easy to get upvotes on answers for any user who knows their stuff. I saw many many such users who meteorically gained rep in no time. I have such user on my tag who has already over 80K rep within one year since registration. If a user finds it hard to get upvotes it means he still has much to learn and thus his judgment regarding if some answer is good or not still needs some enhancement- and it's totally fine. When I just registered I found it very hard to get upvotes simply because I didn't know my stuff. Regarding 15 upvotes, we can make it 10 - that's not the point here.

Comment: @DavidArenburg "_If a user finds it hard to get upvotes it means he still has much to learn and thus his judgment regarding if some answer is good or not still needs some enhancement_" __Wrong__!  People can appreciate quality work long before they can replicate it.  Otherwise professional artists, athletes, writers would not have audiences.  Likewise, people can easily judge whether a post is useful and clear even if they could not have created it by themselves.

Comment: So that's the whole point I'm trying to make. In programming this isn't how it works. A new user that receives a working code don't know *how* this code works. He doesn't know if it memory efficient, if their is a much simpler and fast solution, He doesn't know if this code breaks something else in his code. I've seen way too many bad accepted answers (even heavily downvoted ones just because neither the OP or the answerer can't even tell what's wrong in the answer). Many times when I'm trying to explain the flaw/error in the answer, no one listens simply because they can't understnad me.

Comment: @DavidArenburg wrong again.  Upvotes aren't the end-all-be-all indicator of just the "programming" correctness of a solution.  Rather they also indicate how "clear" (aka easy to understand) a post is.  And really good answers will include the reasons why this code is efficient (or not).  Besides, that's what the rest of the community is for.  A single user only has one vote.

Comment: I like it how you think that your opinion is the absolute right. I'm *not* wrong, I just think otherwise. Either way, as I said before, I don't think that a very novice programmer can judge correctly if a code is good or not (I saw too many of these misjudgments), though with time spent on SO *anyone* can learn- just like we did. On the other hand, an experienced enough programmer can easily gain 10-15 upvotes within the first 2 days on SO (saw many of these too), so for such user my proposal will be an easy barrier to overcome.

Comment: Think of it this way- if you will be presented with 10 questions in math from second grade, will it be hard for you to solve? Though, will you let a guy who can't answer such questions easily to teach your kids math?

Comment: @DavidArenburg no I wouldn't.  And that's not the point.  I would trust him to recommend a tutor.  To __recommend someone who he trusts__ to do the job for him.  That's what voting is about.

Comment: Why will you trust him to recommend a tutor? On what grounds? Maybe he knows a guy that can easily answer these questions, but can't solve a fourth grade questions. But for the first guy the second guys ability to answer second grade is enough.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I would trust him enough because he isn't alone in judging the 4th grade-level tutor.  That single user _might_ be fooled, but the rest of the community probably wouldn't be.  That means they would not recommend the same tutor, perhaps even disapprove of that tutor with a downvote.

Comment: I'll tell you that, judging by the amount of very bad questions/answers with way too many upvotes, that assumption of yours doesn't seem right to me, but I guess we can agree to disagree.

Comment: Waitaminute ... you don't need 15 _upvotes_ / 150 rep in order to vote up other peoples questions & answers, you need only 15 ***rep*** to do so. `Even if your proposed limit were something like 2 upvotes on answers (the equivalent of 20 rep)` ... it ***is*** only 2 upvotes needed to get the necessary rep. (however I agree there are many problems with raising the rep requirement at all)

Comment: I've been seeing ***a lot*** of suspected up-vote fraud lately.  You'll see a ridiculously awful answer, followed by an up-vote or two after about 20-60 seconds. I *highly* suspect shadow accounts being used.  And I'm talking about ***really*** bad questions. So +1 from me.

Comment: @StephenP Yes, currently you only need 15 rep. However, the proposal that this answer is discussing is that you would need 15 upvotes before you could then upvote yourself.

Comment: I didn't see this before "*You don't need to be able to create posts of your own in order to judge the usefulness and clarity of other posts.*" ... We're talking about programming, not painting or Art. You **have** to be able to write things on your own before making any judgement on others work in this particular field  ! As you have to learn english to read an english text, you at least have to learn the basis of a language before being able to read answer on this language, and once you learn the basis, you're able to answer other more newcomers than you basic questions.

Comment: @Tensibai usefulness and clarity are orthogonal concepts.  Usefulness is more technical and would require a minimum knowledge.  Clarity is non-technical and involves communication skills.  If a post is very clear, it can effectively raise the reader's ability to write new code.  Going back to the art analogy, I'm not an impressionist painter.  But a very detailed description and analysis given to me by the museum  (in English instead of art-speak) greatly enhances my understanding of the work.  It can even improve my art-related vocabulary if done well.

Comment: @ryanyuyu And as far as I know, SO aimed to be a Quality Q/A base, this obviously mean the high voted answers have to be correct and not misleading. See the link by Martin James under samgak answer for an example of what we're talking about.

Comment: @ryanyuyu And a crystal clear post explaining 6 by 9 = 42 would still be wrong and a bad post according to SO, even if there's plenty of way to accomplish this, all involves cheating with the maths somewhere.

Comment: @Tensibai yes it would be wrong.  That's what __downvotes__ are for.  Funny how that link you mentioned, there is one (un-voted) comment of dissent but no downvotes.  Please don't hesitate to downvote this meta-answer if you don't agree with most of it.  Likewise, if you actually agree with most of it upvote it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu The main problem is that this answer should not have received 4 upvotes at start... If I start downvoting everything I see which worth it in my point of view, I'll be back to 1 of rep in a few weeks. (P.S: I already voted on each post of this thread)

Comment: @Tensibai why should it not have gotten those upvotes?  It was helpful.  Apparently helpful enough to solve problem, as judged by the OP's accept.  And what's 1 rep to a 4k user?  Moderation is a job for all users of the site, so you should do your fair share and downvote incorrect answers.

Comment: @ryanyuyu on the why: see martin answer below. It's misleading on what it recommends. Sure 1 rep is near nothing, repeat by 50 question/answer a day and you're soon under the 3k which avoid editing question to save them. Moderation is not about punishment (silent downvote) but about improving the site quality in general in my point of view. We should not have to mitigate erratic upvotes

Answer (score 44):

> it seems like only low rep users upvote, while all the high rep users just gave up on the whole system [(from comments)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299875/restrict-up-vote-rights#comment223720_299875)

Agreed. I think the whole voting system needs a revision.

- Any downvote I cast on new questions or answers *without* commenting about why I did so is countered within mere seconds by someone else. This happens every time, unless the post I vote on is clearly and utterly crap.
- Any downvote I cast *after* commenting why I think that was a reasonable thing to do will often cause discussion in comments, and the question still gets a counter-upvote half of the time.
- [Any question that mentions a technique that makes someone go *"Wow that's cool"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298516/questions-with-tens-of-up-votes-are-closed/298518#298518), like Unity or XNA (*Woohoo games!*), MongoDB or other document storage (*Yay web scale!*), image or audio processing (*Cool, I don't know anything about that!*), sockets (*Wow, you can send data over a network?*) or anything else that's more complicated than an `if()` statement will be upvoted within seconds of being posted, regardless the quality of the question. Any downvote I cast based on the contents of the post will be countered even before it's cast.
- Answers are *not* peer reviewed through voting. I have (not on purpose) seen this happen by posting answers to low-hanging-fruit questions: the tone of the answer brought me many upvotes, while the contents were debatable or even plain non-compiling or wrong. Of course I fixed the answer afterwards.
- Many (old) answers that don't explain what they do but provide copy-pasteable code that solves some problem in some way (but introduces others!) is massively upvoted, hardly ever with the pitfalls mentioned in the comments,even more rarely are downvoted, and no competing answers that explain the problem and possible solutions thoroughly are posted.

To me, the score of a post indicates how many people liked it or whose problem it solved directly, not its quality. If we want the latter, we need a change. I don't directly have a proposal for that, but wanted to get this off my chest.

If I'm carefully considering an upvote through reading, fact-checking and possibly running the posted code myself (as opposed to a thoughtless Facebook-esque "like") and I see the post has been upvoted multiple times in the meantime, I often won't vote on it anymore. Democracy is nice and all, but maybe not so in this regard.

Comment: [insert joke about 5 upvotes in 2 minutes that invalidates above post...]

Comment: @2Dee not less nice, just redefine the concept of niceness, so upvotes doesn't mean you are being nice (or downvotes being rude).

Comment: @2Dee a few offensive-flags will auto-delete a comment... flag this answer for moderator attention to get it restored. It wasn't offensive.

Comment: This sounds a little unusual to me.  Even if it's your personal experience, it's not what I generally see with other users on the site.

Comment: So, essentially that would be moving to something more like the concept of up/downvote on Skeptics.SE?

Comment: Counter-votes are problematic, I think this could be solved by a color scale or something similar to show just a ballpark value.  Alternatively, scores could be completely hidden or restricted to a higher privilege tier.

Comment: _To me, the score of a post indicates how many people liked it or whose problem it solved directly, not its quality. If we want the latter, we need a change._ I find this statement baffling--I can think of no better reason for an upvote a post than it solved your problem. _Any question that mentions a technique that makes someone go "Wow that's cool"..._ This is a positive, we all want SO to be comprehensive, no?  Sometimes an imperfect question can still be good in that it will cover a novel area.

Comment: _Many (old) answers that don't explain what they do but provide copy-pasteable code that solves some problem in some way (but introduces others!) is massively upvoted, hardly ever with the pitfalls mentioned in the comments_ People can still add comments/make companion answers, and I would hope you'd point out the pitfalls you see.  A copy-pastable snippet with a good explanation would get even more votes.  In general, it seems to me that putting quality before usefulness is putting the cart before the horse. And people vote for a multitude of reasons and I like to hope that it averages out.

Comment: @j.i.h. no. I find questions where the accepted answer is a copy-pasteable piece of code the least interesting, and I find the quality of such answers appaling. A _good_ answer in my opinion follows the mantra _"perceived problem - possible solution(s) - code implementing those solutions - pitfalls of the mentioned code"_. Not _"copy-pasteable code without explanation"_. How many people "liked" an answer is not an indication of its _quality_. There's already hundreds of thousands of developers in our field who can't program, but only copy-paste. I want Q & A to teach you something.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but would lean that way. This is just a laundry list of things you want to whinge about related to how other people vote, with no argument for believing these other people to be low-rep. The q is tagged discussion, so that's fair play, but I don't think this adds much. And you can hardly complain about weird idiosyncrasies like countervoting when you have your own -- abstaining because you see "multiple" upvotes already (mentioned in the last para). Also, while the OP's comment was about rep, the OP's proposed feature is different.

Comment: @Frank thanks. I cannot prove the votes that I'm talking about to be from low-rep users, so I won't address that. I indeed refrain from voting when the vote-counter updates multiple times while I'm moving my mouse, you can call that a idiosyncrasy indeed. I just mentioned it for completeness - I would very well like to see votes to be cast in a well-thought out manner (which _cannot_ be if a post is mere seconds old, as one hasn't even had the time to thoroughly read it), hence the sneer to democracy, where people vote on gut feeling rather than research.

Comment: @CodeCaster: yes, the comment was auto-nuked on the basis of a naughty word. No, moderators cannot resurrect it (we can only undelete what we deleted ourselves).

Comment: What about a separate vote for "This fixed my problem"?  Or just more verbose rating in general?  Google Play has gone to this recently. Instead of just 1-5 stars, you rate different categories; controls, graphics, etc.  Here we could rate "Post Quality", "helpfulness", "Easy to understand", etc.  Just thinking outloud...

Comment: Few things; downvotes on answers are semi-expensive for low rep users; partially out of respect and partially out of the expense of downvoting, if I find a bad answer I usually give answerers a comment then a significant amount of time to fix the post before downvoting, I usually follow up though. I concur with your observation that "wow that's cool" gets a lot of upvotes, but I'm not sure that's limited to low rep users, I remember a meta post where some high rep users straight up admitted that they do this and think it's even good for the site...

Comment: ... I have also seen the "low hanging fruit gets upvotes"  and the "*wrong* accepted FGITW answer gets upvotes" (IMO this one is particularly harmful sometimes) cases, and I think they are very common. I am guessing that these two limitations are unfortunately by design in SE; as much as we might dislike it, SE does reward people who post first, and popularity; you can argue that this is against SE's goal of creating a repository of information and in my opinion you would be correct.

Answer (score 29):

I'm against this proposal, not because I don't agree that there is a problem, but because I think it won't have much of an effect, and has several downsides (see user000001's answer).

You have observed low-quality answers being upvoted, and immediately jumped to the conclusion without evidence that it is low-rep users (meaning users in the range between the current rep cutoff for allowing upvotes and the proposed cutoff) who are doing it, and that restricting their upvoting abilities is the way to counter it. But since none of us know who is responsible for the upvotes on a given question and answer, this is just speculation. In fact it's reasonable to suspect the opposite. In general, the number of upvotes that someone has cast is roughly proportional to their level of participation on the site, which (apart from a few exceptional individuals) is roughly proportional to their reputation. So given that rep is highly concentrated among a relatively small number of users it's safe to assume that most of the total upvotes are also coming from a small number of users, even if people (allegedly) stop upvoting as much once they get to a certain level of 10K+ or 20K+ (since these users are a tiny percentage of the total). Maybe I'm wrong, but the point is we just don't know.

Low rep users mostly post questions when they have a problem and don't participate otherwise. If you see 5+ upvotes on an answer to a question, it is most likely coming from users who were browsing questions while looking for something to answer and saw the answer and upvoted it. This isn't the typical low rep user, because anyone who is doing that has most likely already answered a few questions and pulled well clear of any minimum threshold for upvoting (current or proposed).

Edit: Just to clarify (in case this is the reason for downvotes) I'm not claiming that number of upvotes follows the exact same distribution as rep, I'm just saying that, similar to rep, it is likely a small number of people responsible for most of the upvoting/downvoting, and they are unlikely to be at the lower end of the rep spectrum that would be affected by any change. If you doubt this then click on a few random profiles of users of different rep levels and see how many times they have voted.

Comment: I wish people downvoting this would explain why. While I don't agree with everything, I believe you might be just right on one key fact here : it's probably not the 1rep users who are upvoting stuff just to counter-balance others, in which case restricting voting rights based on rep would not be ideal. +1

Comment: 'observed low-quality answers being upvoted, and immediately jumped to the conclusion without evidence that it is low-rep users (meaning users in the range between the current rep cutoff for allowing upvotes and the proposed cutoff) who are doing it' umm.. how could evidence, either way, be obtained?

Comment: @MartinJames, we ask a CM to perform an analysis. A lot of the assumptions in this thread need such an analysis.

Comment: @2Dee Mainly "*it's safe to assume that most of the total upvotes are also coming from a small number of users*" Not my observation on `chef` tag at least, few enougth people acting on this tag over 200 rep to be sure they won't be upvoting what is upvoted usually (low frequency tag).

Comment: @Tensibai indeed, behavior seems to vary depending on the tag, which complicates the issue even further :)

Comment: @2Dee I'm unsure the behavior change that much between tags, for many tags I follow (chef, php, awk, regex) the behavior sounds the same, vast majority of low rep users not used/informed of SO rules do bad content. In high frequency tags like awk or regex, there's more active experts who clean off question/answers and the voting system is OK. In php, there's few active experts, and the overall quality is lower. And in Chef, it is so erratic we can forget it.

Comment: Oh... here's one candidate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578103/why-does-stack-overflow-occur-if-we-do-not-declare-our-buffer-as-a-global-variab

Comment: ^^ four upvotes and an accept on a somewhat trivial, multi-duped Q&A. Even given that, the answer is, optimistically, misleading.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 26):

**Is this really an issue?**

I am yet to be convinced that this is an issue. Low quality answers can be usurped by a superior answer, down-voted and flagged for removal for incredibly poor ones.

A [quick analysis](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/339049/437485/reputation-levels) shows that 88% of upvotes and 91% of downvotes are owned by users that now meet the revised criteria's implied reputation threshold (150).

**Should upvotes be seen as a measure of quality?**

The tool tip for an upvote on an answer states: `This answer is useful`. Clearly this is a subjective decision; answers may be useful for a variety of reasons and even low quality answers may be useful. Indeed, an answer may be useful because it was quick and parsimonious rather than drawn out and comprehensive. However, a more comprehensive answer should in the long run be able to assist more people and therefore attract upvotes, if people have the privileges to be able to do so. The proposed policy of limiting voting to those already proven to be proficient in the tag may make it more difficult to attract votes and therefore feedback from the inexperienced, who SO was designed to assist.

**Does this help the community?**

I think that by segregating voting rights on this basis creates a kind of elitism that is not beneficial to the community as a whole. As mentioned above, the inexperienced would be disenfranchised and a clique of those that do have voting rights can conspire to exclude new members. A new community (or tag) with this rule would not allow anyone to vote since there would be no-one to vote to grant other users the right to vote.

Comment: The "*revised criteria's implied reputation threshold (150)*" isn't based on some random rep (as I was trying to emphasize in bold- but with no luck it seems) but by "**by the amount of upvotes you have earned by answering questions only**". This is basically the whole idea behind my question.

Comment: The reason that most votes are held by users who are **now** above the proposed threshold, does mean that they were above the proposed threshold when they voted.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I realise that, but it was the quickest way to provide some relevant evidence to the argument. Aside from bounties, the only feasible way of getting this amount of reputation is from upvotes. Granted this includes questions too, but I don't see why people who have asked well received questions but not provided any answers should be excluded.

Comment: @Jaap No, we cannot know that. However, in any case, They have subsequently proven themselves to be eligible.

Comment: "*who SO was designed to assist*" ? SO was not designed to be a high quality Question/Answer knowledge base ?

Comment: @Tensibai Jeff introduced it as having `the ultimate intent of collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world`. Clearly this is increased faster by helping the inexperienced. http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/

Comment: @James I disagree that helping the inexperienced increase the *sum total of good programming knowledge* in many cases

Comment: @Tensibai Then the help was insufficient.

Comment: @James that's exactly the point of David, the help is insufficient but get nevertheless tons of upvote because it solves the immediate problem for the lazy, and the experienced users seeing the flaw can't overcome this flow of upvote

Answer (score 13):

I don't believe that the threshold for upvoting should be increased. Upvotes are very important for the operation of the system for the following reasons:

- They encourage participation for the people answering. More upvotes means more people willing to answer a question.
- They help distinguish working solutions from flawed/non-working ones. You don't need to be an expert to see that an answer was helpful to you.
- They allow for more people to participate to the various review/moderation procedures, through the reputation that the user gains.

If it wasn't for the problem of sock puppets and voting rings, I would propose the upvote limit to be reduced, not increased.

Regarding the supposed "problem" of some answers having a higher score that someone may believe just, there is a simple solution for this: Downvote the answer, and add a comment explaining what is wrong with it. If your argument is correct and convincing, other people will also downvote, so the score of the answer will be "corrected".

Comment: I don't agree with your second point (and not so much with the others as well...), I saw lots of answers that look correct (mostly because the poster claims it is) being upvoted (probably by someone who didn't completely understand what the answer does...)

Comment: Downvoting the answers to the VLQ questions from the rings and puppets costs rep.  I would lose it faster than I could gain it.

Comment: The flaw with the conclusion is the "automatic" upvote on certain tags, non working/blatantly dangerous answers are upvoted by low rep users, which outclass the downvotes by experts anyhow

Comment: @MartinJames If you suspect that a question/answer was posted just for gaining rep through a voting ring, you should probably flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: I don't believe that in the current state "They help distinguish working solutions for flawed/non-working ones", quite the contrary in many cases. Programing isn't just about copy pasting some code on some random example and see that it accidentally worked. I believe that code should be bullet proof for various situations. It should be memory efficient, fast, it should not potentially brake other code and etc. Every language has it's own philosophy too, a working code doesn't mean that this is the correct way to solve the problem in *that* specific language as it would in some other language.

Comment: _"[upvotes] encourage participation for the people answering"_ - you shouldn't care. You should want to post answers to increase the amount of high-quality content on the web, not for imaginary points. _"[upvotes] help distinguish working solutions for flawed/non-working ones"_ - they don't, see my answer. _"[reputation gained through upvotes] allows for more people to participate to the various review/moderation procedures"_ - the proposal is not to never give out reputation points anymore.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I agree that all these are desirable properties for an answer. However, there are many cases where a non-optimal answer is sufficient for solving a problem. Something is often better than nothing.

Comment: And many times it is worse than nothing.

Comment: ^^^ what @DavidArenburg says. So many upvotes on so much crapness:((

Answer (score 13):

While I understand your concern, I think changing the minimum rep requirement would, as said in other answers, cause more problems than it solves. It would very likely offer a disincentive to answering questions from new users and further the level of frustration experienced by new users.

I would suggest that exposing up/downvote totals at a lower threshold and trying to encourage users to downvote answers more often would solve the problem.

It may sound a little silly but I think the -1 rep for downvoting is a problem for newer users. In their desire to accrue rep and privileges they're more hesitant to downvote which is part of the problem you're seeing.

I also think that downvotes should probably carry a little more weight. It currently takes 5 downvotes to offset the rep earned from 1 upvote, so users are given an incentive to leave their bad answers in place.

**The problem isn't so much that new users are upvoting crap, its that they aren't downvoting, and when they do those downvotes aren't as visible or effective as they could be.**

Comment: Answer downvote of `-4` seems fair considering that Answer-upvote to Answer-downvote would be the same proportion as Question-upvote to Question-downvote.

Answer (score 9):

Although I understand the point David made, I think his solution is a bit too radical and will discourage new users from participating (as was already extensively put forward in several other answers).

Another possibility is a more gradual increase in upvoting rights.  For example:
1 upvote per day with 15/25 rep, 5 per day by 100 rep, 10 by 250, from 500 as it is now (or something like that).

New users get voting rights quite early and get rewarded with additional voting rights when they gain rep, thus also addressing the engagement point @Thomas mentioned. Furthermore, such a gradual increase will force them think twice to who they will give their precious upvote, thus making them really consider what a good post is.

Comment: This is similar to the current behavior for [determining the number of flags a user gets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251621/how-are-flag-limits-calculated)

Comment: I would guess most users with low reputation that would be up-voting bad questions/answers are doing so because they got help from rather then their quality so likely wont change anything.

Comment: @JoeW I don't get your point. This approach would mean that their (supposedly bad) voting behavior would be limited. It could even be 2 votes/day at 15 rep, with one more vote granted per 100 rep, up to 40, like flags and like deletion votes http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: What I am saying is I think the low rep users are more likely to find a question and vote on it via google rather than from browsing the site and would be unlikely to use many votes in a day anyway.

Comment: Like the idea. @JoeW - the votes from users who *found* answer via Google and the answer helped are exactly the once that help SO. The problematic once are for people randomly clicking on multiple questions and voting  in a way whatever they feel like and not based on whether it helped OR whether it is correct (i.e. based on "let me help low-rep user" or "I'll upvote my friend/coworker") - and as you've pointed first group will not be hurt by restriction at all and damage from second one will be limited. (Not sure if your comment was even disagreement with the post at all).

Comment: @Frank I like the idea of granting one more vote per 100 rep gained. It would give several intermediate goals in gaining reputation. The only downside would be that is will become a bit harder to get several voting badges (suffrage, vox populi, civic duty & electorate).

Answer (score -2):

I understand your concern, but I am afraid I disagree. The reason are both logical and ideological. I will list all reasons.

1) The reasoning is not completely logical. The problem is how you define a good or bad answer and a good or bad question, which may be subjective. Inexperienced users will likely ask fundamental questions. Does this mean that there are bad questions? My opinion is that they does not. Further, an answer to a fundamental question does not need to be bad just because the question is fundamental. Neither does an answer necessarily need to be good, just because it answers a difficult question. I have an excellent example on a good fundamental question, with a really good answer about [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array). Here I would rather promote a notice in the beginning which provides example on good reasons to upvote. For example, a question should not be upvoted if a simple google search gives the answer or if the question seems to be useful to a small amount of users. Further an answer should not be upvoted unless it can be considered helpful (In particular, if a user is unable to confirm its correctness it should definitely not be upvoted and if a user finds an answer undoubtedly incorrect it should definitely be downvoted).

2) Does a short, concise answer mean that a question is bad? My opinion here is that this depends on the question. A short concise question may require a short concise answer. This does not necessarily mean that the question or the answer is bad. This is an example of this question, [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable). The question is fairly fundamental, but it have got many upvoted, since there is no explicitly stated difference in the documentation. The programmer is left to analyze this on his own. I will not comment on the quality of the answer, since I does not know enough for this. This question could of course gain on a more thorough answer as well, but sometimes a short answer is enough.

3) Low rep users, does not necessarily mean stupid users or ignorant users. They not even need to be "noobies". Further, a high rep user does not mean the user does not throw away arbitrary upvotes or downvotes. I would rather see that new users are made aware of the problem and encouraged to be restrictive with upvotes and downvotes and that they are instructed when these tools are suitable to use.

4) Raising the rep for voting would decrease the liberalism on in the community. It would, as already stated, be a basis for elitism. It gives away a message as "You are not good enough to make your voice heard". This makes sense for voting to national elections etc, since young people does not have the same responsibilities in society as older people. In a community like SE, it does however, not make sense. Anyone can join here and anyone who joins must start with asking a question or answer a question. If any of these gets upvoted the user can be declared as a real person (thus not a machine) and also a person with, at least, some knowledge about the necessary topic. The ideology should have a high level of liberalism and assume that each person can be held responsible for his own actions. Then, people which have been proven trustworthy and dedicated to SE should of course still, be offered further responsibilities as it is now.

So to concluded, the reputation does not need to say much about the members abilities to distinguish good answers from bad ones. It does neither say much about the users ability to take responsibilities for its own actions. I have seen bad answers with high rep and good answer with low rep. Still, it is impossible to say if there always have been this way or if they are bad due to aging. It is also hard to say, by looking at the post, if there what reputation the users voting for it has. So I does really believe that we should keep the requirements as they already are.

Comment: "*Low rep users, does not necessarily mean stupid users or ignorant users. They not even need to be "noobies"*" - Never neither said or implied that. Also, I'm not talking in "rep" terms at all here (your fourth and fifth points)

Answer (score -5):

I think that we should have some sort of "guest up-vote" system. Rep 15+ means you can up-vote, but it makes a minimized rep up for recipient. The votes could even be viewed in a breakdown of new users and people whose up-votes meant full power of 10 rep. They would get this power after they have achieved 100 rep, because that means they won't just spam their votes. This also means the "vox populi" badge won't inspire people to just up-vote everything they see until they get it. I don't think we should raise the entire bar. This also prevents someone making two accounts and spamming their votes between them into the squillions. I feel like newbies should be able to say what they like, and also that they could even have a no-effect no-cost *down-vote* as well, that the poster would see alone, and that it came from a new user, so that people whose opinions matter can vote either way without too much gain or loss of rep for veterans.

Answer (score -14):

A compromise method would be to add a voting filter, something like "*also show reputable voters separately*".  Users could check a box on their profile, possibly with a radio button reputation number, (i.e. *1000*, *10,000*, *50,000*...).  It'd a sort of Senate/House or Lords/Commons contrast.  By default such filters would be turned *off*, so new users would see just what we see today.

An added feature might be to refine filters so that one might select by reputation within particular *tags* -- perhaps we don't wish to include hi-rep *intercal* expert votes when considering answers for *befunge*, we might only want to see the votes of *befunge* experts.

So there could be an algorithm to rank by the most reputable voters in the relevent tags concerned.

---

Note: in certain cases such filters might be used to find out how certain users voted.  Such as if only one user had *n* points, and we filtered by *n* votes.

One remedy for that might include forbidding threshold values of *n* where *n* would be revealing, so if there were too few users above *n*, any radio button to select by values greater than *n/10* would vanish.

Answer (score -28):

I think the current upvote/downvote system is OK, but we can add some new matrix. The **power** of an upvote/downvote would depend upon the person's [reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). For example, the upvote of a person having 1000 reputation will matter more than a person having 50 reputation. Similar is the case with downvote also.

This way we can give everyone a right of upvoting/downvoting and the best questions are only upvoted.

Comment: This is inherently unfair.  Well-established users would become too influential.

Comment: It also assumes that everybody who's knowledgeable on a subject has been busily earning rep on SO for that subject.  If Jon Skeet didn't have 147K in C#, he'd still be a leading expert on the matter

Comment: @ryanyuyu you have a point. my bad .  For downvoters, was just sharing my geniun thoughts!!!

Comment: @SidharthDash Downvotes on meta don't necessarily mean the post is bad, just that they disagree with it, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu On the other hand, Google PageRank is based on this concept. While I'm against counting different votes differently, giving posts a hidden "relevance score" based on upvotes from people with tag badges and making them appear near the top of a page, could improve the site experience for people who only read the first 2 answers.

Comment: I like this idea, although I think the effect of high rep should be tiny. Something like having a bronze badge in one of the tags on a question should make votes count 10% more, silver 25% and gold 50%. The problem though is that even if that was considered fair, it would require redesign of votes to accommodate fractional votes... Not worth it

Comment: @pnuts of course rep means something- it means you've made Stack Overflow better.  But that has nothing to do with whether you know C#.

Comment: I fear this would have a bad impact on the democracy of the community. It would be as if the people with better education got more votes in the national election. Except for that, it could probably impact on the fundamental questions as well, which unexperienced programmers normally ask. These questions are probably the ones which have reach most new programmers during the years of SE.