# Should I be (more) careful when upvoting questions?

Tags: discussion

I usually always upvote questions that show research on the OP's part, are well structured, contain only the relevant parts of the code for a certain problem, among other qualities.

However, I don't thoroughly check the post before I upvote it since I've always thought that upvotes weren't that significant. Recently, I've been wondering if "*carelessly*" upvoting posts might have a negative impact on how those posts may get more visibility than perhaps another with better content but that no user upvoted (which isn't that uncommon, especially when bounties are involved).

Ideally, how should I use my upvotes in order to be useful?

Comment: *"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear."* Beyond that, let your conscience be your guide.

Comment: If you really want to be sure, you could add in doing a quick check for duplicates if you're not already doing that.

Comment: I admit, it is kind of irritating when I see upvotes on questions that could've been answered by literally Googling the title, or bare homework assignment dumps. The strategy behind these upvotes is (I think) to upvote the question to give it good standing (won't be Roomba'd, etc.), then answer it and collect rep. The only downside is cluttering SO with cruft.

Comment: Does your "shows research-effort" include "neither a short google-search nor a short SE search will find the answer"?

Comment: You should prepare, well in advance, to handle a good question that deserves an upvote.  Ensure you have soft carpets around your office in case you fall off your chair with the shock. Keep a bottle of Whisky or Brandy handy in a desk drawer.

Comment: Do you really need other people to tell you how to vote?

Comment: Note especially the __is useful__ part. Much more imprtant than nice formatting or quantity of code included imo..

Comment: ﹢1, well structured question

Comment: Frankly, I don't think the voting system and user participation are very effective at dealing with question quality anymore. I'll see a couple questions a month that everyone agrees is good, and many that everyone agrees is bad, but I'll also see a lot of stuff like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971587/python-using-sort-in-a-function) that gets three upvotes and a pile of answers (including a user with a gold tag badge) before the duplicate closure goes through. It makes me lose faith in the rep system.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think "short google-search" is a very subjective thing. Some peoples google-fu is better than others. Additionally, an advanced user might know how to sift through the results quickly while a novice will have trouble knowing wrong from right in the results.

Comment: Not to mention little tweaks that make google search more effective, such as blocking w3schools.

Comment: @jkeuhlen A "short google-search", at least the kind *most* mean in that context, consists of nothing more than plucking parts of the question into google and looking if one gets lucky. While that's beyond a really *astonishing* number of askers, I don't see how those could and/or should be reasonably excused.

Comment: I just saw a "used SO's question title field instead of Google search box" question, and the asker said that he couldn't use the regex documentation that appeared as the top Google result because he wasn't aware of regex. As it turns out, learning things is logically impossible.

Answer (score 77):

You should not be doing any action that impacts others without your due diligence.

In the case of upvoting questions, you should be evaluating for the proper criteria:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear.

If you are not actually performing an evaluation of this criteria, don't vote. You could be promoting garbage on the site (increasing noise in the face of a constant signal).

Upvotes are more points than downvotes as well, so you might be giving a reward to a poster that is posting garbage when your one upvote is not getting outweighed by the downvotes they receive. Then we get people with reputation sufficient to moderate the site and other people's posts that do nothing but post garbage all day.

There is no harm in not voting. If you don't have a clear judgment on a post, refrain from voting, editing, closing or moderating.

Comment: I do try to follow an appropriate criteria, I don't randomly upvote, as I've mentioned. It's just that I sometimes wonder if it's more benefitial to upvote or to restrain from voting. Thanks for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score 52):

I hardly ever upvote questions, because I very rarely see a question that is good in my opinion.

I only upvote when I'm familiar with the problem space, and if the question is unique, useful, clear and shows research effort. If I'm not familiar with the problem space (i.e. another language, a library I've never used or a concept that is new to me altogether), I certainly won't upvote and maybe will downvote if the question has obvious flaws.

My stance in the Q&A [Restrict up vote rights](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299877/266143) is that I don't understand why some questions even get upvoted. They're unclear, lack context (yes, *"Why do you want to do this?"* is a valid comment under a controversial question, especially if that commenter is experienced in the subject), lack code or lack knowledge of English. Yet they are upvoted because they contain the word "socket", or so it seems (*"Wow, you're doing network programming! I don't know anything about that, have a like!"*). All the same we shouldn't upvote questions just because they contain no grammatical errors. Nor questions that are answered by selecting the title, right-clicking it and selecting "Search the web for ..." (unless the answer is *not* on SO).

We shouldn't give an "A for effort", this isn't kindergarten. It's no excuse that you're inexperienced, all of us have been. Using a search engine is a skill just like reading. You *need* to learn to search, to debug, to break up your problem in smaller pieces. If you can't, you won't get far in this profession, and you can't expect Stack Overflow to either fulfill that role for you or teach it to you. You need (self-) education to become a good developer, and you need to learn to ask good questions in order to get good help.

As others have addressed, it is *hard* to write a good question. That is correct. Yes, it is scary to put your first post on the angry internet. So you better make sure it is clear, readable, the problem understandable and reproducible. There are tons of guides that explain how to write a good question. If it isn't good, don't upvote.

Comment: .... upvoted for *this isn't kindergarten* ....

Comment: With unique, I hope you are meaning it's *at least* a valuable sign-post, not neccessarily a unique problem....

Comment: @Deduplicator "unique" in the sense of "not a duplicate".

Comment: "It's no excuse that you're inexperienced, all of us have been" - amen. In my opinion, it used to be a lot more fun to be inexperienced. Nowadays you don't even have to hunt for information anymore, back in the day I had to stalk second hand book stores to try and catch a book I wanted, or make a trip to the library and socialize with other information-gatherers. And today? Cold clicks from a silent home and ping-pong posts in websites. Sigh.

Comment: I reserve my upvotes for posts that are well written, *and* contain a problem/bug/logic error that isn't immediately obvious to me. and well written/researched "how do i do x" questions that aren't dupes, because those don't get enough upvotes.

Comment: Many potential upvoters expect the user posing a question to not just explain the problem to them, but ask meta-questions. While it might be interesting to you to know why I want to do this - if the problem is clearly stated and potentially useful, what's it to you? This isn't a blog. Also, some people do not speak English natively (gasp); should they open a version of SO in their own language? Obviously not. We should help them with edits of their grammar/phrasing and appreciate their contribution.

Comment: @einpoklum _"if the problem is clearly stated and potentially useful"_ - then you won't hear of me.

Comment: @CodeCaster: But I do hear from other people... "what do you want this for?" "Oh, if you must know, I need it to help me produce an apple that tastes like chicken" and then people start commenting about _that_ since it sounds a lot more exciting than, say, some C++ template instantiation question or what not.

Comment: @einpoklum comparisons hardly ever make sense, try to come up with a real example. Anyway, OP is not obliged to answer such questions. I often see or sometimes post comments asking "Why?" under question that are extremely convoluted, old-fashoned, fundamentally broken or just impossible - and I can only say that about subjects I am knowledged about.

Comment: @CodeCaster: So instead of "Why?" one could take the time to comment "It seems extremely convoluted to foo the bar. Can you explain why you can't just baz it instead?"

Comment: @einpoklum who says I don't...

Comment: Maybe you do, but many don't :-(

Comment: I think this post contradicts quite a bit the [Embrace the non-googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) way of thinking. We were supposed to be *the* source of information, not expecting people to work up based on other sites. At least in principle, I know lot of cases where that isn't practical, but still - I claim that non-googlers are often also a good thing.

Comment: "If you can't, you won't get far in this profession..." ...What universe do you live in? I wanna go there.

Comment: @eis that is not relevant at all, and I addressed the research part in my answer. I'm talking about questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005599/regex-find-word-in-string). Why would someone upvote that?

Answer (score 31):

No, you do not need to be careful.  If in your opinion a question satisfies the criteria for upvoting, *"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"*, then you should upvote the question.

(As a sidenote, the criteria for *downvoting* a question is the negation of the criteria for upvoting, *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*.)

There are three parts to the upvoting criteria:

1. *"This question **shows** research effort"*  (emphasis added).

   I interpret this criterion and the use of the word "shows" to mean that in some way the text of the question demonstrates (such as by citing or linking to an authoritative source, or mentioning an approach that has been tried) that the asker of the question has put some effort into answering the question for himself/herself.

   This criterion should weed out the questions that can be answered with a few minutes of searching the Internet, Stack Overflow, or relevant documentation, because these questions typically provide nothing to show that the question asker has researched the problem.
2. *"[the question] is useful"*

   This is the criterion that I think is the most difficult to apply because you can't definitively say whether the question is useful *in general*.  The question is hopefully useful to the person who asked the question.  However, unless the question is useful to you personally, you cannot say that the question is useful to someone else.

   Perhaps the "it is useful" criterion is best evaluated by considering whether the question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (as in, useful to the site by virtue of being on-topic), and the question is not likely to be a duplicate.
3. *"[the question is] clear"*

   I interpret this criterion to mean that the post appears to include enough detail for someone to be able to provide a good answer.

In addition, I partially agree [with CodeCaster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302331/196844) in that you should only upvote a question if you are familiar with the problem space.

I tend to be more liberal in upvoting questions.  To justify my position, consider:

- Upvoting a question provides only +5 reputation.

  I know that some people adopt a strategy of asking many poor questions in order to gain reputation.  However, you can usually determine whether someone is doing this by looking at their question-asking history.  And, if someone's goal is to gain reputation as quickly as possible, it is far more lucrative to write answers, especially for unanswered questions with an active bounty.
- The criteria for upvoting a question does not require you to "thoroughly check" the question.
- Upvoting a question that in your opinion meets the criteria for upvoting, but which in actuality is a bad question, is not nearly as harmful as upvoting bad answers.

  Per one of CodeCaster's comments, it should be noted that if you tend to upvote questions that have been downvoted by others, then you may need to reconsider how you decide whether to upvote questions.
- In order for there to be good answers on Stack Overflow, there must be good questions.
- From my experience, it is very difficult to ask a question.  Many questions can be answered for oneself with a few minutes of searching.  A significant portion of the remaining questions can be answered by searching and reading information on related topics, or perhaps by reading source code.  The remaining questions are usually too broad or too narrow in scope to be useful on Stack Overflow.  Thus, to someone who is trying to ask good questions on Stack Overflow, very few questions are candidates for questions on Stack Overflow.

  When such a rare candidate question comes along, it is a fair amount of work to write the question on Stack Overflow.  At least, it is for me.  It is necessary to write the part of the question to "show" research effort.  It may be necessary to provide context.  It may be necessary to prepare a code sample, properly trimmed to remove irrelevant details.  All of this work for not much benefit in terms of reputation gained.  Of course, the real benefit is getting an answer to your question, but it seems to me that this is not as likely to occur if the question receives no upvotes.

You have written that it isn't uncommon to see other questions with better content that no one has upvoted.  Isn't the solution to this problem, then, for everyone to be more liberal with upvoting questions?

It really is a bad feeling to put a lot of effort into writing what you think is a good question on Stack Overflow and no one, or hardly anyone, upvotes your question.

There is a [Socratic badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic) that is awarded for *"Ask[ing] a good question on 100 separate days, and maintain[ing] a positive question record"*.  As of this writing, only 2,002 people have earned this badge.  I have this badge set as my "badge to track" (currently at 88/100), so I know how difficult it is to earn.  Compare this with the number of times the answer badges have been awarded ([Nice Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) - 591,533 times, [Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/24/good-answer) - 168,409 times, [Great Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) - 24,567 times).  Perhaps more comparable are the gold tag badge (4.5k times) and silver tag badge (14.8k times).

By the way, for the purpose of the Socratic badge, a "good question" is a question that has received just one upvote.

In my (slightly biased) opinion, people should upvote questions a lot more frequently than they do currently.

I think that it is interesting to examine for oneself the list of unanswered questions with no upvotes: [is:q closed:no duplicate:no score:0 answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+score%3A0+answers%3A0)

In the past hour or so of examining questions that appeared interesting to me from their title or tags, I have downvoted 3, taken no action on 13, upvoted 6, and answered 1.  I would be interested to know what stats others have.

Comment: " Many questions can be answered for oneself with a few minutes of searching." This is part of the problem. As SO (and other resources) get better and better, it is much harder to ask a *good* question, as so many questions are already solved online. However, since (most) askers of bad questions are people who don't bother to search elsewhere for help, the number of bad questions stays just as high, and the noise-to-signal ratio climbs and climbs. This is the reason it is increasingly important that people should be careful about voting up bad questions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your observations about how hard it is to write a good question!  When trying to solve coding problems (things that are on-topic for SO), there will almost always be a solution online to all but the most obscure, and even these will have some hints or clues in the documentation somewhere.  In my experience, this results in the only questions that I've been unable to answer myself only barely passing the 'not too narrow' criteron.  Yes, upvote questions, the good ones are in a minority and deserve some recognition.

Comment: You really seem to be advocating upvoting any question, because it's hard to write a good question. _"Upvoting [...] a bad question, is not nearly as harmful as upvoting bad answers"_ - it is. It's showing OP and others that it's good to ask bad questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, I am not.  What part of my answer led you to believe this, because I would like to clarify it.  Also, you misquoted me by leaving out the most important part of the sentence.  I wrote "Upvoting a question *that in your opinion meets the criteria for upvoting, but which in actuality is a bad question*, is not nearly as harmful as upvoting bad answers."  I did not write, and I did not intend to imply, that people should upvote questions that they think are bad.

Comment: @Daniel it's not a particular quote but the entire tone of your answer that makes me think so, starting at the first sentence _"You do not need to be careful [when voting]"_ and ending at the last _"people should upvote [...] more"_. Re the botched quote, if you're upvoting questions that you deem good but others find bad, then perhaps you need to reevaluate what makes a question "good", and validate that you're still on par with the community's consensus. Still, I stand by my previous comment, upvoting bad questions is equally bad, if not worse than upvoting bad answers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to point out with that search link, but try [is:q closed:no score:0 answers:0](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+score%3A0+answers%3A0+). :)

Comment: @CodeCaster That's much better!  I didn't know that those search options were available.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with the tone of Mad Chadders. For noobs, it's hard to know what to search for. Sometimes, in an effort to post a good question, I'll search, try and find relative articles, read them, and voila! I answer my own question by trying to post a good one. Sometimes, however,  I can search for hours trying to find the solution to my answer, and when I go to post a question, I have nothing to show for it because I can't find anything that is truly relevant.

It's like in the Matrix when Morpheus is being interogated, and they are pondering about why the serum isn't working when one muses "Perhaps we aren't asking the right questions". So I come here and meekly ask for help to be pointed in the right direction. Granted, in the grand total of two questions I've asked here (all the others I've figured out in the research process) it was a typo or lack of knowledge on my part, but I was greatly appreciative of the assistance given. Also, being aware of the altogether uselessness of my questions and the goal of SO to store useful questions and answers, I deleted my questions as well. The upvotes I received in the process, however, were probably helpful in getting a solution.

Comment: If the dupe is a useful signpost (it described the problem reasonably clearly but with different words), that's fine. Otherwise, it's simply a waste. And as long as that typo-question wasn't indicative of lack of basic research, that's fine too. Most often, it is though. And kudos for cleaning up after yourself when finding out that it was one of those damn typos, and not actually a post which might be useful for others. Assuming that was right.

Answer (score -10):

For what it's worth, I think it's ok to upvote. As a relative newbie, there is certainly a lot of difference between the way someone with 95K reputation (not sure if there is such a person just picked a high number at random) would search vs what someone that just joined today would.

ie the 95K guy probably knows exactly the right words to search where the newbie just knows they aren't good enough at coding yet, so they maybe tried googling the answer "vba varying range to another account" (just an theoretical example) but couldn't find it so they came here. After reading the question the more experienced user might have better ideas for searching.

For the more advanced user, rather than assuming laziness a response of what they would use to search for if they didn't know off the top of their head, would be more helpful. I've seen responses like this has already been answered, with a link and then they close the question, but nothing about how the already answered link was found.

It would help the newbies more get a response hey I found this by searching using these terms "x, y, z", here's a link where this was already resolved, I've closed your question since it is a duplicate. I hope this makes a little more sense.

Comment: Of course it's ok to upvote, as long as the post you're upvoting deserves it. I've seen people add what they searched to find answers in the past, and it's almost always done in a rude or condescending way. I don't feel those comments are that useful.

Comment: Nobody's saying it's not OK to upvote. You need to evaluate whether it's a good question before you do, though. Please don't "pity-upvote" poor questions of low-rep users for the sole reason of them being "newbs".

Comment: The sad fact is, though, that a huge proportion of questions asked can be solved by simply Googling the title (or even just a few keywords from it). If someone knows enough to write this title, then they should have searched first, and the question should not be upvoted.

Comment: I think maybe my comment was misunderstood. I'm not saying to pity vote people, if one asks a lazy question down vote it or abstain, but sometimes it might be more helpful to explain to them why it was lazy instead of just down voting it with no feedback. I guess based on the negative votes I hit a nerve.

@Kevin B I've seen that too but I still think that is better than no feedback at all. Easier to learn when one has some example ie. "I googled your title but changed this one word and here are the 50 places that explain this", good point though.

Comment: I do think people misunderstood your answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Actually, a large mass of people are "saying" it's not ok to upvote by, well, very rarely upvoting.