# Do I up-vote too much?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, voting, upvotes

*I have tried to see if this is a duplicate but couldn't find it which I was surprised by...*

I guess this is probably quite subjective but as a relatively new user I feel it's difficult to know whether to upvote on people's questions or not.

In the tags that I frequent, answers usually get up-voted by the OP but rarely others and questions also rarely. I try to upvote anything I think is helpful or correct in terms of answers and anything which is either worded well or intriguing as a question. I get the impression that people are hanging around waiting for new users asking a question poorly so they have an easy downvote (I usually try to help instead of this approach).

Even though the review area encourages upvoting on **"Looks OK"** questions I feel like I am one of the few being generous with voting.

Essentially my query is, is this a problem? Do I need to be more choosy with what I like? What are the possible ramifications of more/fewer people doing this. In my head it's positive behaviour which helps people out but I'm trying to understand the flip-side.

Just to give an example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344024/match-a-path-vlookup/39344153#39344153) I upvoted an answer which had been marked as such by the OP but the OP hadn't deemed it worthy of an up-vote.

---

Just to give further clarification, I don't believe I'm carelessly upvoting, that's not the purpose of my question. I think that it would be irresponsible to upvote a poor question mainly as it would give the OP carte-blanche to continue to write questions of dubious quality. I'm more intrigued with the balance between apathetically not voting (I don't know who that benefits if anyone) or voting either way. If people are apathetic but there are good questions / answers not getting voted then I don't get it. Aside from using up all your votes in a day there's no downside as long as the quality is good.

Comment: [Should I be (more) careful when upvoting questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302275/should-i-be-more-careful-when-upvoting-questions/302279), [What should a minimal answer contain?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298804/what-should-a-minimal-answer-contain).

Comment: Are you upvoting low quality questions to try to be "helpful"?  Or are you just ignoring all low quality questions and only ever voting on quality questions?

Comment: See also the converse question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Comment: I don't upvote on low quality questions, for me I think they have to be useful for someone out there or well worded to be deemed of a good quality. Conversely I'm not averse to down-voting poor questions but I'm probably more likely to give the benefit of the doubt to new users. Thanks for the links, I'll take a look now.

Comment: Votes are the grease that keep the SO wheel turning.  Voting patterns in the [excel] and [vba] tag are not great.  Not what you'd call an ideal tag community, I don't want to get into the history behind it since it is all kinda negative  So sure, feel free to keep those positive vibes humming.

Comment: if you are not down voting crap and only up voting marginal stuff you are doing it wrong, especially with questions since down voting crap questions are free

Comment: *I get the impression that people are hanging around waiting for new users asking a question poorly so they have an easy downvote* No, new questions just get the most attention.

Comment: If you upvote an answer, make sure you can attest it is correct. Don't upvote just because it looks good, because it already has many upvotes or because the OP marked it as accepted. When you upvote an answer, it is because you understand the question and you agree that it is a/the correct solution to that problem.

Comment: You should be downvoting too though

Comment: _I get the impression that people are hanging around waiting for new users asking a question poorly so they have an easy downvote_ I get the impression people hang around these for an oppertunity to give an easy answer, not an oppertunity for an easy downvote.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1068/most-upvoted-tags. Some communities are much better than others, the Delphi coders are not on that list but I've noticed they are a small community and know how to reward each other so better questions standout - all the way back to google search rankings. Not trying to get the meta effect happening on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094845/) but I recently got a Silver badge for it and noticed approx 1.5 people visited it everyday over 4 years. A bit disappointing to see 1 vote when its fairly popular.

Comment: I really wish there was a question **Do I downvote too much?** and I could flag it as an exact opposite.

Comment: @jeremy Most of those 1.5 people who visited it over the past 4 years probably did not have accounts on the site and were not able to upvote it if they wanted to. The vast majority of Stack Overflow's traffic comes in from search engines with anonymous user accounts.

Comment: @CodyGray I personally love [so], its my fav site on the interwebs. I have spoken to a few friends who use it daily that are unregistered and its just a pity. Good to see people like OP :)

Comment: This appears to be an amazing clickbait question to attract enough upvotes for the OP to propel their reputation from zero to [insert some large number here]

Comment: @user3728501 You don't get rep from upvotes on meta.

Comment: "Essentially my query is, is this a problem?" Definitely no.

Comment: @VincentSavard "If you upvote an answer, make sure you can attest it is correct." Really? You check all the contributions you upvote up to the smallest details? What about obscure corner cases? Should I attest about them too? Are you sure this is what all the other voters are doing here? I think demanding this is unrealistic but you have a good point there. I wonder how many people upvote an answer just because others upvoted it? I would like to make psychological experiments with fake scores displayed and measure this effect because it surely exists on SO. The herd instinct is deep within us.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My mistake I assumed you do

Comment: I voted to close as opinion based, not as duplicate.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes, if it is good content, vote it up. But it is just as important to downvote posts if they deserve it; you have a maximum of 40 votes (up and down combined) a day, don't refrain from downvoting because you need to save the votes for upvoting.

Note that a question might be worded well, but it can still be a duplicate which is asked plenty of times before on this site. Questions that don't show enough research effort should be downvoted, regardless of the form.

See also the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) on **Why is voting important**:

> Voting is central to our model of providing quality questions and answers; it is how ...
>
> ...good content rises to the top
>   ...incorrect content falls to the bottom
>   ...users who consistently provide useful content accrue reputation and are granted more privileges on the site

Comment: It is easier to find stuff to down vote. I spend votes on those. That makes awarding only an handful of up votes the highlight of my day ...

Comment: Agreed 100%, particularly on _why_ to up-vote. I see far too many posts (especially questions) which are up-voted wrongly. They are unclear, show no research (often the duplicate is found searching on the exact title of the question), and yet they garner up-votes. Yet other well-written and answerable questions languish. We need more _correct_ voting of all sorts, but I suspect better and more up-voting correctly would go a long way toward improving things.

Comment: "it can still be a duplicate which is asked plenty of times before on this site" I wonder if someone downvoted all teh thingz [right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/218384).

Comment: If the question is still well asked, and the duplicate is reasonably difficult to find without prior knowledge, I'll upvote because it's a good signpost.  This doesn't happen most of the time though.

Comment: @davidism s/most of the time// ;)

Answer (score 19):

Just be aware that you must be sure that the post you're upvoting really *is* helpful.

In the past I upvoted lots of crap like a stupid monkey just because the answers seemed helpful, already had gazillions of upvotes, and I had no expertise.

Now I would want to downvote these answers instead, but the upvotes are locked.

For some reason Stack Overflow does not want to allow us to change our minds, and locks the votes until the posts is edited. But editing lots of posts just to change the vote would be bad.

So vote carefully, unless you want to regret later. Votes are almost permanent.

Comment: I already start regretting I upvoted this answer...

Comment: Overwhelmed by the question of whether I should upvote that comment

Comment: It's not too hard to edit in a space character and then change your vote. The only disadvantages are that the edit is confusing and your downvote is no longer anonymous.

Comment: @Suragch that creates noise though, it pushes the question onto people's front page feed as if there's new content when there isn't.

Comment: _In the past I upvoted lots of crap like a stupid monkey just because the answers seemed helpful, ... , and I had no expertise .... Now I would want to downvote these answers instead._ Really? Don't you feel your vote should remain as it was helpful then even if it isn't now? I used to think stabilisers on my bike were helpful but don't any more but I don't reckon I should push people away from them as they may still be of use to people who are in my old position.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland This site exists to create (and promote) high quality content. Rewarding users for producing good content is not a vote's main goal. Personally i was in a similar position when starting on SO; i had upvoted several posts that looked good. I wish i could change it, since many of those posts were average and some were even bad or parrot-answers.

Comment: @Fermi paradox How do we measure high quality content? Surely the content that is the most helpful? After all, what point is high quality content (whatever else the measure) if it isn't helpful to anyone? I could be misreading the answer here but what I'm getting is OP was a beginner in X so upvoted  answers to to beginner questions in X. Now OP is an expert in X so wants to downvote the previously upvoted answers. I think the question lies with _why_ he wants to downvote them. Just because it is a beginner question doesn't mean it isn't high quality.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland The problem is not that they answered a beginner question. The problem is that they advised bad practice. But back then I didn't now it was bad practice.

Comment: Thanks @Oriol, that makes more sense and sounds like a legitimate reason.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I think that the problem you point out is real.  What is the distinction between a useful beginner question and a useless beginner question?  If you can get the answer in a quick google, is it necessarily bad?  In the Programming forum a novice was completely confused by the errors non-unique variable names were causing.  It's a very elementary property that every programmer should know, but everyone has to start somewhere.  It's useful to all novices at that level, but it ended up at 0 or below...

Answer (score 16):

The general idea I get is that voting is personal. There are guidelines (upvote the good, downvote the bad), of course, but no one requires you to explain why you upvoted or downvoted. Your reason is your own. The only thing explicitly not allowed is voting fraud.

Some people are stingy with the upvotes and generous with the downvotes. Others like yourself are generous with the upvotes and only occasionally give a downvote. The system needs both types, but I'm personally thankful for people like you, otherwise I probably would have quit asking and answering questions a long time ago. When you upvote, it's like saying, "Yeah, I have the same question, too!" or, "Thank you for volunteering your time to help me with this." I don't think you can say "thank you" or "I agree" too much.

My personal voting philosophy is to downvote wrong answers or very poor questions. However, I upvote much more than I downvote. I upvote any question that is the same as mine and any answer that helps me get a little closer to solving my problem. *(Well, sometimes I've upvoted a 99 just to make it a 100, but that's not a good reason. Don't do that.)*

Comment: One could probably look at the ratio of up/downvotes and look at the distribution for all users. I found for myself that I'm quite happy and confident with about 2-4 times as much upvotes than downvotes (depending a bit on the stackexchange community). To me this means that the good stuff I see still outweighs the crap I see, so it's still a worthwhile endeavour. If the downvotes would outweigh the upvotes I would actually start to worry.

Comment: @Trilarion, that would be an interesting statistic.

Comment: I upvote everytime I find the question meets what I'm looking for, even if it could be improved, or the existing answers are not helpful.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/466049/upvote-downvote-ratio

Comment: @CodyGray, Thanks. SEDE is something I need to learn how to use some day. Will it average the ratio for all users to give a single ratio for the whole site?

Comment: @CodyGray It seems Eric Lippert is a bit picky. At least he found one contribution worth to be upvoted. ;)

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to share some statistics, which I originally used in [an answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6962/104611) on Code Review's meta.

> I decided to see what the average score (`avg(score)`) is for posts that aren't closed, only including things that were posted since 1/1/16 (`where Creationdate >= ''2016-01-01'' and closeddate is null`).

Note that the x-axis is score. The y-axis is essentially meaningless, except it helps group things based on the x-axis.

> [image]

This graph shows data from ALL sites (except metas). Note that I chose to look at only a specific set of posts: recent, open posts.

Closed posts represent content that, in its present form, is off-topic for the site it was posted on; that's why I exclude it.

Obviously, new content is all that you should be seeing in most queues (especially if you are given the opportunity to vote). The reason why I feel that the scores on new content is particularly important is that new users have only posted new content. In order to have new dedicated users (the type that helps sustain the site and produce high quality material), there needs to be voting happening on their new posts.

Code Review ranks at a 2, and guess where Stack Overflow is? Stack Overflow is one of the points falling off the graph at **0** average score. Even looking at different subsets of that data: answers vs. questions, excluding negative scoring posts, etc., Stack Overflow does not move from its spot at 0.

Again, let me stress the importance of voting, especially up voting. Without up votes we have nobody with tag badges. Reputation is gained at a much slower rate, and this prevents new privileges from being gained. The lack of voting prevents content from being sorted, and up votes can also be the difference (as far as the system is concerned) between an answered and unanswered question.

This lack of voting is also devastating to those who contribute to the site. Morally, I mean. There's only so much that a person can tolerate in the way of ignored contributions before they give up.

Down voting also has its purposes: it helps with content removal, quality filtering, post bans, etc.

As long as you are only up voting good content (on-topic, well-researched, clear), then you shouldn't feel any guilt.

Comment: So the X axis is post score, and the Y axis is what?

Comment: @PeterCordes The Y axis is largely meaningless, except it helps group things.

Comment: Group the things into average score 0-20, 21-75, 76-120, etc? Why those cut-off points? And colors are meaningless yes? This seems like probably a really interesting answer, but it'd be great if you could back up a step and explain the graph for those of us who've been out of data analysis for a while

Comment: It isn't surprising that posts get fewer upvotes on Stack Overflow than other sites. Even on Meta, which is a fairly large and active site, it is *possible* for a dedicated user to browse through *most* of the questions that get asked per-day and cast a vote. That is not even possible for a single popular *tag* on Stack Overflow. So this is just a "big-city" problem that you've found evidence for. Not terribly interesting. *"Without up votes we have nobody with tag badges...reputation...privileges."* Not a real problem on SO, either. We've got plenty of that to go around.

Comment: @CodyGray not sure it is just because stack overflow is large. There are also more people using it. I also get the feeling there aren't enough upvotes.

Comment: @henry The **x-axis** is score. The colors are automatically assigned by SEDE (and I have no control over them).

Comment: Oh, right. So the graph is saying, "There are some SE sites where the average upvote count of open questions asked in 2016 before early August is 0, a lot where it's 1, and then it tapers off with the highest score being 11." Is that correct? Still confused by the choice to offset stack the groups (there must be an actual term for this) -- why not sit them all of the x axis? (Not saying you did something wrong, actually asking) [edit:  wait, no, rereading your original codereview post, is it the average number of votes cast on open 2016-01-01 - 2016-08-something question per registered user?]

Comment: @henry Yes, although the numbers are clearly rounded. As for the offsets, it was really just easiest to make the numbering like that.

Comment: I probably should have been asking all this on your codereview post heh, but did you see the note I tacked on to that last comment? Is it the average question score or the average number of votes cast per user on the selected questions?

Comment: @henry The Code Review post had two sections: the first section was about how much the average user votes, and the second part was about average score. The second part is where the graphs came from. (I reused the one graph from that post, so the data might have changed slightly since then.)

Comment: Got it! Now that I understand, I can see how you would think it was self-explanatory. Been (too long) a while since I read things like your codereview post, just needed a little time to get the brain warmed up. Thanks!

Comment: How can the average of the score be only integers?

Comment: "Without up votes we have nobody with tag badges. Reputation is gained at a much slower rate, and this prevents new privileges from being gained." Maybe that is the plan of the not-upvoters?

Comment: You ought to state in your answer that it is the average post score rounded to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 8):

I see votes as the currency of SO.

This gamification and self moderation has been core to the success of SO and it's what drives the right behaviour and quick feedback. Coupled with multiple reviews and votes on votes (i.e. Looks OK / Recommend deletion when reviewing) it provides a fairly robust system where good intentions generally win out.

So it is important to vote and vote often. You could view voting as the quantitative easing of SO. It gives the personal reward of recognition too and motivation for contributors to keep on contributing.

Vote carefully and accurately to the best of your ability and remember that it is also about behaviour, acting responsibly, as well as using the wider range of tools (edits, flags, reviews).

Remember - Garbage in Garbage out...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a right or wrong. Personally, I'm usually only up-voting a question if

- I'm interested in getting an answer myself (so when I don't know the answer offhand or am not sure)
- I consider it a really valuable piece of information.

In particular, when I'm googling for a problem and find the answer on SO I'll up-vote both, the question and the answer

I usually down vote if

- I consider the question hard to understand or answer (Either due to a really poor language or because lots of information is missing) or
- It is absolutely trivial (like questions, that get answered 10 minutes into a language tutorial)

otherwise I just leave it be. In particular I don't necessarily up-vote every question I answer.