# Add feature to mark answer as wrong (for immediate removal)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, vote-to-delete

As stated by [Your Common Sense](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) in an answer:

> On Stack Overflow, nobody ever cares for the answer correctness or
>   fact checking.

Refer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345074/2142994

**We must change this to give quality answers and remove factually inaccurate ones.**

This is a request for a feature to mark factually wrong answers.
As stated in another question([Are blatantly wrong answers very low quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality)), false answers can't even be marked as "Low Quality". ***The only option is down-vote but in many cases I see that an answer gets one or two down-votes but doesn't get deleted (as they haven't yet received enough down-votes).***

Example:

Question - [Difference between Hive internal tables and external tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17038414/2142994)

Wrong Answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979347/2142994

This answer is factually wrong yet up-voted by somebody, I have down-voted it but why don't we have a direct option to ***mark it for deletion due to factually inaccuracy***?

So why not add a **Mark as Factually Inaccurate** option in the flagging options?

Comment: You'd need an additional queue of domain experts to review those flags. Or give additional super-powers to gold-badge holders. I don't see either as a workable solution. IMO votes are the proper tool for this. It doesn't always work, but that's the way it goes.

Comment: *"yet up-voted by somebody"* - Welcome to the wonderul world of "pity upvotes", where the content or the quality of a post doesn't matter.

Comment: The real problem imho is that an upvote gains more reputation than an downvote, while a Upvote is free and a Downvote not, if the answer is not going to be deleted. Theoreticaly voting is a good indicator if something should be deleted or not. It just not works the way we want to.

Comment: @Tom I doubt pity upvotes are a thing. Votes are just pretty random with a slight tendency to upvote high quality and downvote low quality. Maybe [Tim finally found his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397), and it put another sequence of events into effect.

Comment: It is just abject nonsense, everybody cares about correct answers.  That some users are not so interested in *his* version of a correct answer is entirely his own doing.  You can't reasonably base such a drastic site change on such nonsense.

Comment: _"As stated by Your Common Sense"_ Well there's your problem. As ironic as it is, What YCS says often comes closer to fiction than fact.

Comment: There are a lot of questions.  There are a lot of answers.  Some answers will be 'wrong'.  There is, at least, one answer in [multithreading] that has two upvotes, is accepted, and cannot possibly ever work.   If an answer is 'wrong' downvote it and add a comment, explaining why it's wrong.  Then, (important), don't go near it again.

Comment: @HansPassant In case of the example I have given "his version of correct answer" is wrong. There should be an easy way to delete such wrong answers.

Comment: @yivi Users with Gold Badges in the mentioned skill/tag should be allowed to delete the marked answer. The users with Gold Badge in these Tags could get these in a separate queue.

Comment: @AniMenon, frankly, I'm ok with leaving the accuracy filter in hands of the community via vote casting. It is **far** from perfect. But then again, everything is.

Comment: @yivi I agree but adding such an option and allowing knowledgeable users to easily clear wrong answers will help get rid of such deceiving answers.

Answer (score 18):

> So why not add a **Mark as Factually Inaccurate** option in the flagging options?

Because who would investigate and act on those flags? It certainly wouldn't be moderators; we cannot possibly be experts in every technology covered on this website.

You'd need to have experts in the relevant tag(s) evaluate those answers.

And...we already have this feature—**downvotes** and delete votes!

If you see an answer that is factually incorrect, mark it with a downvote. When the post has accumulated enough downvotes that it has a negative score, [trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) who are experts in the relevant technologies can vote to delete it.

Comment: Though it would be nice if the 10K/20K moderator tools worked better so we could filter for delete votes in our tags.

Comment: For some people still, it could not harm to have an upvote-audit :D

Comment: Might be something to revisit once you guys get through the close-vote queue, @NathanOliver :-p

Comment: har har har :p Just kill my dreams why don't you ;)

Comment: Tiny's [userscript](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/MagicTagReview2.user.js) works fairly nice to filter delete votes on tag.

Comment: @CodyGray Users with Gold Badges in the mentioned skill/tag should be allowed to delete the marked answer.

Comment: If *trusted users* are to delete it then it has to be _"The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether."_, which is not the case in most cases. Wrong answers are an attempt to answer but the answer just happens to be wrong. So any "attempt" to answer shouldn't be deleted by ***Trusted Users***.