# Why is this audit answer not an answer?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, first-post-review

I just failed the following audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19449197

As far as I can tell, this is not a good, but at least a valid answer. The asker asks why emails are bouncing and how they can see why, the answerer tells them they should check their addressed against a verification service.

Is it because the answer is too general? Would recommending a specific site have improved it? What would have made this an answer?

According to this meta post, it being an incorrect or inadequate answer to the question is not a reason to flag it as VLQ: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345024/2730399

And according to this meta post, any answer that makes any attempt to answer a question is a valid answer: [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: The answer just says there are tools to do what is needed but no information on how to actually do it.

Comment: @Joe W I would count that as an attempt to answer the question regardless. It's not a good answer of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a review, meaning you need to make your best effort in giving the right resolution for good answer/question.

Even adding comment to the user that will help him understand how to write a good answer this/next time is important, for example, see what a reviewer wrote:

> his does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review – S.M. Mar 23 at 12:51

If you see a problem with the user answer, in this case, that it could have been a comment, try to change it by writing a comment explaining why his current answer isn't sufficient.

Comment: @francescalus updated my answer, it was similar to review question

Comment: This reminds me a bit of [this uber meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309061/388562) about piling on comments. Doesn't simply upvoting an existing comment also enables the I'm Done option?