# Why are incorrect, downvoted answers not deleted?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

I have come across many answers which are fundamentally incorrect and have been downvoted, but have not been deleted. I had flagged a few as NAA, but the flags were declined as **flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer**.

I have downvoted most of them, but don't like losing 1 reputation for no reason, especially when the OP of the answer has 1 rep so won't be affected/notified, or when the OP has not visited the site for a *very* long time so the crap on the page is here to stay.

What should/can we do about these answers?

1. [stackoverflow.com/a/55583894/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55583894/12860895)
2. [stackoverflow.com/a/63709859/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63709859/12860895)
3. [stackoverflow.com/a/53729366/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53729366/12860895)
4. [stackoverflow.com/a/24535005/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535005/12860895)
5. [stackoverflow.com/a/20601918/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20601918/12860895)
6. [stackoverflow.com/a/8255862/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255862/12860895)
7. [stackoverflow.com/a/64403688/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64403688/12860895)
8. [stackoverflow.com/a/64403268/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64403268/12860895)
9. [stackoverflow.com/a/64404396/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64404396/12860895)
10. [stackoverflow.com/a/37292713/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37292713/12860895)
11. [stackoverflow.com/a/64403066/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64403066/12860895)
12. [stackoverflow.com/a/62041620/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041620/12860895)
13. [stackoverflow.com/a/64242892/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64242892/12860895)
14. [stackoverflow.com/a/43055723/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43055723/12860895)
15. [stackoverflow.com/a/37119201/12860895](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37119201/12860895)

Comment: Sometimes they are useful. If there isn't a good answer they might at least tell you what not to do.

Comment: @RobertLongson the reason I downvoted and flagged them is that they were incorrect and don't solve the problem at all

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality

Comment: Why do you think active users with only 1 rep won't be affected or notified?

Comment: @BSMP users with 1 rep don't lose rep when they get downvoted, so they don't get a reputation change notification

Comment: OK. I think someone who's intending to be active on the site will notice the score on their answer went down anyway but I didn't know you stop getting notifications for anything that lowers reputation at 1 rep.

Comment: @BSMP if your post gets downvoted, the only way you'll ever get notified is by a reputation change notification. If you have 1 rep you can't lose any more, so not only do you not get a notification, I lose 1 rep for downvoting and they lose nothing and never know about it

Comment: What you could try when you find such bad posts is to go to the (in this case) JavaScript chat room on SO https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript and see if you can find any high rep JavaScript users who can help casting delete votes. Casting delete votes on incorrect or very low quality content is fine, but you often need domain knowledge, which moderators don't necessarily have.

Comment: I thought about mentioning that option, @Lundin, but I'm hesitant to encourage folks to spam chat rooms with low-quality answers...

Comment: @CodyGray Eh, if SO bothers to host all those chat rooms (and provide moderation for them), then the least they can do is to help out with some delete reviews now and then. The "SOCVR" chat is far less likely to have enough domain experts lurking around.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is not the site's general policy to delete answers on the basis that they are technically incorrect. Incorrect answers should be dealt with by *downvoting* them.

There are essentially two reasons why we do not generally delete answers on the basis of inaccuracies:

1. Moderators and reviewers cannot be expected to have expertise on all subjects covered by Stack Overflow. Therefore, we cannot judge the correctness or accuracy of answers. (This is why your flag was declined: moderators will *not* try to make these judgments.)
2. Incorrect answers can *sometimes* still provide useful information (*e.g.*, what *not* to do), as long as they are displayed with sufficient warning. Downvotes provide other viewers with that warning.

There is one exception to this general rule: [trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) who have subject matter expertise can, in their judgment, cast delete votes on answers they feel are incorrect and harmful. But this is a rather special case, given the limited number of trusted users, and the even smaller likelihood that there will be enough trusted users with relevant subject-matter expertise for a particular answer. Furthermore—and perhaps even more importantly—there is no review queue or other escalation mechanism to bring suspected incorrect answers to the attention of such trusted users for possible deletion, so you really should just keep downvoting them.

In addition to downvoting, you may optionally choose to leave a comment explaining why the answer is wrong or irrelevant.