# Does a reviewer have to verify correctness of an answer before voting "Looks Ok"?

Tags: support, review-queues, first-answers

What should I do if I find an answer which is good quality, but I am not sure whether it answers the question correctly or not? Should I use "Looks Ok" or Skip it?

Comment: Reviews aren't there to judge if they answer the question; that's what votes are for. If the answer "looks good" then it looks good; even if it's wrong. If you, however, don't feel confident, then skip.

Comment: I don't understand, why would people downvote questions when it makes you lose your reputation? I reviewed some answers and downvoted them and I lost 4 of my reputation points.

Comment: Because people are more interested with the quality of the site. Moreover, at some point additional reputation doesn't have much value.

Comment: *"why would people downvote questions when it makes you lose your reputation?"* Downvoted questions doesn't cost you any reputation. Downvoting answers costs you 1 reputation. But why would you **not** downvote a bad answer? Reputation has *nothing* to do with it.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes at a certain point but that certain point hasn't come for me yet and if I downvote 5 more answers I will lose my privilege to access review queues.

Comment: @Larnu I am sorry I meant answers, not questions. I know downvoting questions doesn't affect the reputation.

Comment: it is like any other answer you come across, if you don't like it downvote it or ignore/skip it

Comment: @ArchitGargi when you see wrong answer you have two options - downvote to *help* future visitors by indicating that the answer is wrong, or upvote/not vote to *troll* future visitors by implying that the answer is useful. Not everyone choses to troll and hence some select to downvote.

Comment: "Yes at a certain point but that certain point hasn't come for me yet and if I downvote 5 more answers I will lose my privilege to access review queues." This, in my opinion, is a bug in the process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The text on the "Looks OK" option in "First Answers" is, I have to admit, not especially helpful in your situation:

> This answer is good as-is and not low quality (be sure to vote
> accordingly).

Seemingly, this suggests that your *"which is good quality"* assessment is enough, even though you have doubts over *"not sure whether it answers the question correctly or not"*.

If we look at the text from "Looks OK" in the related, "Late Answers" queue, we see this:

> Answer addresses the question, is unique, and is not low quality.

Again, no indication here that the answer needs to be *correct*, just that it is *relevant*.

Thirdly, in the "Low Quality Answers" queue, we have this:

> This is an honest attempt at answering the question and is not low
> quality.

This, in my mind, confirms what I have deduced from the previous two captions: here, it is explicitly spelled out that being an *honest attempt at answering* is sufficient for "Looks OK".

Now, although I have mentioned three different review queues here, and formed a  sort of hybrid description of what counts as "Looks OK", I think that the similarity between these queues, and the fact that they are addressing very similar/related issues, gives me reasonable licence to do just that.

So, in summary, if an answer is, in your opinion, a good quality post, then "Looks OK" is an acceptable review verdict, whether or not the answer is actually a correct solution to the problem in hand. If you *know* that it is incorrect, then feel free to cast a downvote in conjunction with your "Looks OK" verdict (even if that combination of votes seems rather weird). You can also add custom comments, of course, should you wish to point out any errors or inaccuracies in the answer – and remember that either leaving a comment or casting a downvote will enable the "Other action" button.

Finally: "Skip" is never really a bad option if you have any doubts at all about how to review a particular post.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.

First, expecting reviewers to verify the correctness of every answer they review would be a lot to ask. It would have the effect that only people who were domain experts in the particular area that the OP was asking about could review answers.

Secondly, [wrong (or even blatantly wrong) answers are not very low quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345023/are-blatantly-wrong-answers-very-low-quality). As pointed out there, that's what downvotes are for.

Third, we don't necessarily need to delete all incorrect answers. In fact, incorrect (or even outright dangerous) answers can actually be helpful (if they have a negative score and comments explaining why people shouldn't do that) because they can help steer people away from mistakes or misunderstandings.

For example, I once saw an answer that suggested determining the size of a file by loading the entire thing into memory. The language in question already has standard library calls that can determine that much more quickly, and the comments pointed out that that's an extremely dangerous (and unnecessarily slow) way to determine it. I'm guessing that the answerer wasn't the first person to try something like that, and hopefully the downvotes and comments will deter some other people from making the same mistake.

I saw a different case where an answerer recommended using `HttpClient` in a `using` block. For those that are unfamiliar with C#, this is a dangerous practice that's contrary to how Microsoft recommends using the class; doing so can result in port exhaustion. I downvoted it, commented explaining why that's incorrect, and added another answer explaining what the OP should do instead and why; hopefully the answer helped someone avoid that common mistake.