# Is it the correct way to upvote an answer?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, upvotes

I would like to know if it is correct to upvote any question/answer that helped me, without care the date of the question/answer. 
For example, I'm programming with Node.js and I need to fix some problem that I have with this. Then I look in Stack Overflow and find the solution to my problem.

So, at this point, is correct to upvote the question/answer that solved a problem that I had?
I made this question because when I did read the help and it says (I can't find it now but I remember that) something like: "Don't be generous".

Comment: That's exactly what voting is **for**. If content **helped you**, upvoting is exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: Why would it be incorrect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote .. _date of the question/answer_ is not really relevant. If it is helpful upvote

Comment: @Cerbrus I think it could be incorrect because is like you are giving reputation to "everybody".

Comment: I would like to know where you found that *don't be generous*. Can you dig through your browser history, find that page and edit the link in your question?

Comment: @rene There are severals topics on Meta dealing with *don't upvotes answers on dup or bad questions*. Maybe it can be the source of his misunderstanding?

Comment: @Mistalis that is possible but my search in the help or meta didn't directly hit that term so I was wondering in which context they found that. Also because that could possible reverse the influx of down votes on this question a bit ...

Comment: I can't find this in the Help or on Meta either. It's possible someone said this on Meta but that it's since been deleted. I did find this post, which has more discussion on when to up vote: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302275/should-i-be-more-careful-when-upvoting-questions

Comment: @Mistalis "bad question" and "useful question" are orthogonal concepts in my book (this in not necessary common understanding) - I believe that questions considered "low quality" by SO standard could for whatever reason turn out to be extremely useful and upvotes is the way to detect that. Note that it is relatively easy to improve quality of the question, but very hard to predict usefulness over time (sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-last-commits-in-git - no research shown, 14k+ votes).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> This answer is useful

This is the description of the upvote on an answer. If it helped you, of course you can upvote it. I would say it is recommended to do so, as it is exactly what upvotes stand for.

*PS: If a question shows research effort and is useful and clear, think about upvoting it as well.*