# Add a voting attribute option

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

I was reading one of the hot meta questions about restricting voting rights here:

[Restrict up vote rights](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299875/restrict-up-vote-rights)

Based on several discussions in the comments and the answers themselves it seems like the community is against that for various very valid reasons, but one of the items that stuck out to me was the fact that there seems to be a need for understanding users votes either up or down. The common answer to this type of ask is in relation to notifying the author of the question or answer. In my case I am looking at this from the point of someone who is searching for an answer to their problem and wants to dissect the reasons for the votes. I look at this tool as a way to tell if its downvoted because there are some technical errors but that the solution is valid otherwise I would want to know that as a simple vote and lack of comments may not detail that enough. It has been identified in other threads some people down vote because they don't agree with the solution (or upvote because of interest). These are much different reasons, and as a searcher I would want to know this! I think there might be a somewhat useful solution here.

Could we add some sort of pop-up window similar to the queues that would allow users to choose their "strongest/best" reason for their vote and then display the various vote count reasons just under the vote count/favorite question star OR show the question details if someone clicks on the vote count so as not to clutter the page?

Depending on the options this could distinguish between the voters who choose technically accurate questions/answers versus those who like the question because they have a similar problem.

These would be different for answers versus questions, but I have mixed the question and answer options below just as an example! **I am not saying any of these would be used but just as a proof of concept!**

> Please choose the strongest/main reason you are voting on this
>   question:
>
> Upvote:
>
> - The question is well-written and provides value to the community
> - I am having the same issue / I want to know the solution to the question.
> - The answer is thorough and fulfills the OP's requirements.
>
> Downvote:
>
> - This answer has several technical inaccuracies
> - This answer has become obsolete (obsolete methods, the links are dead, etc)
> - This question has not been accurately or thoroughly researched enough by the OP.

Comment: I think if this would be something optional, so that the voting works the exact same way as before, just that if you want to take some extra time to choose a reason for your vote you can then this FR maybe has a better chance.

Comment: @Kendra That question is very close to what I am asking. I did not find it when searching for this already being asked as I didn't consider it anonymous reasons so much as allowing me to dissect the WHY of a question so I can make an informed decision if it can help me or not.

Comment: *"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"* / *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"* - why can't people just spend a second to hover over the vote buttons and read?

Answer (score 13):

> the fact that there seems to be a need for understanding users votes either up or down

No. No there doesn't.

If I see a question voted at -3, I really don't care if it's because the post has poor spelling, is just a terrible question, or doesn't have a code example. The score of -3 tells me the most important thing: it's a crap question. Exactly how it is crap is irrelevant to me.

Similarly, if I see a question at +10, I really don't care exactly why; I'll see for myself when I look at it.

Now, maybe you want to have the OP informed of why the votes were cast. Well, if it's an upvote, I fail to see how it matters. Will it change the way a user uses the site? Probably not, since they're clearly already doing a decent job. And if it's a downvote, we already have ways of explaining why we downvoted. It's called "commenting".

And if you don't want to comment when downvoting, that's perfectly fine. The downvotes aren't there for the OP so much as to keep people from wasting their time with garbage questions/answers.

Comment: Nicol, the fact that the question (thanks to @Kenda's comment) is brought up alot means this matters to some part of the community, but in response to your who cares why it's downvoted may matter quite a bit.

For example if its downvoted because there are some technical errors but that the solution is valid otherwise I would want to know that. Also as has been identified in other threads some people down vote because they don't agree with the solution. This is much different from completely irrelevant and useful questions.

Comment: @Shawn: And the fact that they're heavily voted against shows that the majority of the community *doesn't* want this.

Comment: The part of the community that often gets downvoted frequently is unfortunately rather large.

Comment: @KevinB:  I've seen it largely not depend on the person as much as the suggestion.  Heck, even *I've* had certain suggestions/ideas downvoted significantly.  Not a reflection on myself, but a reflection on the idea posed instead.