# How is upvoting popular questions fair?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation, upvotes

Recently I came upon few users with significant amount of reputation.

Quick check shows those users have answered a very few questions, but actually have asked questions users find popular (i.e. how to iterate list and remove item at the same time), thus those questions themselves often have 300+ upvotes, resulting in massive reputation boost for OP.

It is often the case that the OP hasn't put any effort in previous research, nor did any tests, nor followed the question conventions, which should be the reason for question upvoting.

So how is that reputation boost fair compared to us other users and what can the community do to reduce this problem?

Comment: How is it unfair?

Comment: _what can the community do to reduce this problem?_ Nothing, people vote on the answer and not the question, the answer is normally good and useful for a lot of other people (even if the question is _bad_), hence why they get upvoted so much. Also, sometimes people forget simple things, Google them, end up here and upvote the answer, I've done it many times.

Comment: In that case, edit the question to the best of your knowledge to improve it as much as possible. I understand one won't get any rewards for that. But then, are we here just for virtual points?

Comment: @George I am referring to the upvoting of the question itself, not the answer. This also raises the question is answering popular question worth getting so many upvotes just because you bet the clock. But this is another story

Comment: I understand the sentiment behind your concerns, but I think the voting process is fair. Stack Overflow isn't solely about accruing points, it's a community moderated Q&A platform where users get to decide what they vote up or down. As members of this community, we should be vigilant in editing questions/answers we think need improvement if they're not up to par.

Comment: Maybe it helps if we categorize up-voting popular questions as voting fraud. That should enable the voting reversal script to correct these votes and for severe cases allow moderators to take action and suspend the users that participate in this popular voting, which is the root cause after all. If this works we can declare a complete tag popular....  Or am I carried away by the idea?

Comment: Why the downvote to my question?

Comment: see also: [Life isn't fair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202652/165773)

Comment: this doesn't answer why the downvote. Also why the linked OP has 8 downvotes on a normal question. Is this the way SO users tend to reward OPs caring enough to post on Meta?

Comment: also if you have answer to my question, you rather should post as an answer, not comment

Comment: @MartinAsenov See the paragraph [voting is different on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). (Voting to indicate agreement or disagreement is also not only limited to questions tagged *feature-request* - it applies to basically all questions.)

Comment: I can understand your point. There are users who made bad questions without doing any decent research (and got +300 upvotes anyway), have not answered any question, and have way more reputation than people who put effort in answering questions. Maybe, +5 is too much for upvote on questions.

Comment: Ultimately, you can't prevent other users from disagreeing with you on whether a question is good or not.

Comment: Check out the long duplicate chain!

Answer (score 32):

> ...but actually have asked questions users find popular...

I'm not sure what that even means. I don't upvote questions because I find them *popular*, I upvote them when I find them *useful*. It doesn't matter if the question is 8 years old and already has 300 upvotes, if it's a question that I had myself and it leads me to an answer, I'll usually upvote it. I don't think this is a problem that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 11):

Repeat after me: **Stack Overflow is *not* about rep**. So please stop harvesting it as if it is gold and please stop worrying about it either.

The only thing Stack Overflow is meant for is to create a *quality* data base for questions and answers for programmers.

Now regarding your question, if you feel that the question is very badly formatted, shows no research, off-topic, etc., you have few options:

- Comment
- Downvote
- Edit and improve it (if the OP is not responsive)
- Vote to close

If the question is not salvageable (which is not the case here, judging by the votes) you can even try to delete it (which is a bit more involved).

That's pretty much it (unless I forgot something).

And finally, you shouldn't be worried that after your (optional) edit the question will suddenly become very good and the original OP will earn even more rep, you know why? Correct- **because Stack Overflow is *not* about rep**, rather about creating a quality Q/A database- and your edit just made a significant contribution to that purpose (if that question is on top of Googles search results).

As a side note, I do agree that many upvotes on very bad *answers* (regardless of the rep that comes with it) could severely hurt the purpose of the site and I once posted a [controversial Meta about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299875/restrict-up-vote-rights), but that is a whole different story.